# Почему нельзя получить точное число?

Tags: python, float

Объясните, из-за чего происходит вот такая штука:

```
>>> 1 - 0.7
0.30000000000000004
```

и как с этим бороться?

Comment: [Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: Вопрос, кстати, не специфический для питона.

Comment: Это сейчас мне стало ясно, а тогда я был маленький и глупый.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/1365)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Такова природа чисел с плавающей запятой: они описываются через экспоненту, и их "шаг" может выглядеть довольно странно, однако обычно он достаточно мал, чтобы избежать серьезных ошибок. В документации, насколько понял, рекомендуют использовать [round()](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/floatingpoint.html).

Comment: Спасибо за подсказку!

Comment: @Fike проблема не в экспоненте, как уже описано в ответе @insolor

Comment: @alexlz, мы написали, в общем-то, одно и то же, экспонента только там не обычное е.

Comment: Еще можно использовать числа с фиксированной точностью (Decimal)

Comment: @samoilow Ну а можно бы и числа с плавающей запятой, но десятичные :).  (Правда не скажу, есть ли такие устройства). Двоичные числа с фиксированной запятой порождают ту же проблему.
@Fike лениво написать лишнее слово? "обычное e" -- это 2.718281828459045 (я понял, что Вы хотели написать "обычное 10", но написали немного другое).

Comment: @alexlz, я ответил немного позже, поэтому мой ответ можно считать уточняющим :)

@Fike, если быть совсем точным, числа с плавающей запятой хранятся в виде мантиссы (множителя) и порядка (показателя степени), основание подразумевается равным 2. И под мантиссу и под порядок отводится ограниченное количество двоичных разрядов, отсюда и всяческие погрешности.

Answer (score 16):

Дело в том, что в памяти числа хранятся в двоичном виде, а 0.3 в двоичном виде выглядит как бесконечная периодическая дробь (0.0100110011001...). В память бесконечное число цифр, понятное дело, не запишешь, поэтому реально там хранится число *чуть меньше*, чем 0.3. При вычитании этого числа из 1 и выводе на экран эта небольшая разница и выплывает наружу. Что с этим делать - смириться с несовершенством мира и при выводе округлять до приемлемого числа знаков.

Подробнее о представлении чисел с плавающей запятой тонкостях операций с ними: [статья на Хабре](http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/)

Answer (score 2):

Ещё можно попытаться привести числа с плавающей запятой к целым числам. Например, следующее неравенство:

```
1 - 0.7 > 0.3
```

(на которое python мне ответил True) можно заменить на эквивалентное домножив обе части на 10:

```
10 - 7 > 3
```

Тут я уже, как и ожидалось, получил False.

Comment: разве это ответ на заданный вопрос?

Comment: Ну, человек спросил "как с этим бороться?". Я предложил вариант как можно в определённой ситуации бороться с ошибками в округлении.