# Сравнение чисел с плавающей точкой

Tags: c, float

Почему в результате выполнения следующего кода:

```
float x=-3.2; 
printf("%d",x+3.2==0)
```

Получим ноль а не один, как можно было бы ожидать?

Comment: переформулируйте пожалуйста заголовок вопроса, он не имеет отношения к самому вопросу

Comment: Вдогонку к предыдущему комментарию http://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/

Comment: @Dmi7ry, полагаю, уместно будет также оставить ссылку на хабр к ответу, так как именно на него будем ссылаться при возникновении вопросов-дубликатов.

Comment: Я потерялся. Я в с++ совсем новичек. 1курс. Этот вопрос мне попал на экзамене . я на него так и не ответил. А ответ узнать хотелось бы.

Comment: Ответ - нельзя сравнивать числа с плавающей точкой на равенство. Почему - расписано в [этом ответе](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82).

Comment: @soon добавил комментарий к ответу

Comment: Вообще-то тут в этом вопросе есть серъезная и важная тонкость - смешение `float` и `double` типов в выражениях, которое в первую очередь и приводит к неожиданным результатам. Приликованный "дубликат" рассказывает об общих проблемах плавающей арифметики, но не затрагивает этой важной детали.

Comment: Рассказы о том, что плавающие числа "нельзя сравнивать на равенство" - это все немножко не о том. В реальности язык С достаточно детерминистичен, чтобы давать некоторые гарантии. Например, вот такой код `double f = 3.2; bool b = f == 3.2;` *обязан* инциализировать `b` как `true`. А вот код `float f = 3.2; bool b = f == 3.2;` - не обязан. Это - ключевой момент, не освещенный по ссылке. А вы взяли и закрыли вопрос...