# Десятичные дроби типа double в java

Tags: java, типы-данных, double

Есть код:

```
public class Drob {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 0.1;
        System.out.println(x+x);
        System.out.println(x+x+x);      // Три раза прибавили X
        System.out.println(x+x+x+x+x);  // Пять раз прибавили X
        System.out.println(x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x+x); //Десять раз прибавили X
    }
}
```

На выходе он даёт это:

```
0.2
0.30000000000000004
0.5
0.9999999999999999
```

Против первого и третьего ответа у меня возражений нет. Но откуда на хвосте `4*(10^-17)` во втором ответе? И как это соотносится с `-1*(10^-16)` в четвертом ответе?

Comment: Почитайте [тут](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B9) (и по ссылкам). А если ответить совсем коротко (и не исчерпывающе), то так работает железо (электронные схемы).

Comment: Скорее всего, эта тема уже обговаривалась [тут](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/10105).

Comment: Так и есть. Действительно оговоривалась. Но я через поисковик не нашел.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Давайте зайдём с другой стороны. По [стандарту IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985#Representation_of_numbers)*, число типа `double` хранится в виде ± *n* × 2<sup>*k*</sup>. Это значит, что при записи

```
double d = 0.1;
```

число в переменной `d` вовсе не будет равно `0.1`, потому что `0.1` не представимо в указанном виде. Ясно, почему?** Вместо этого в `d` будет записано какое-то приближение к `0.1`.

Поэтому и `d + d + (10 раз) + d` не будет в точности равно 1.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [OMG Ponies!!!](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2009/11/02/omg-ponies-aka-humanity-epic-fail/)

---

*По [стандарту языка](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.2.3), числа с плавающей запятой соответствуют стандарту IEEE 754. (И не только в Java, кстати.)

**Потому что все числа упомянутого в стандарте IEEE 754 вида представляются в виде натуральной дроби, знаменатель которой есть степень двойки, а 1/10 таким числом не является. Действительно, если *m*/2<sup>*n*</sup> = 1/10, то 10 × *m* = 2<sup>*n*</sup>, и левая часть делится на 5, а правая нет.

Comment: и откуда вы всё это знаете?

Comment: @AndrewKachalin: Нам рассказывали на лекциях. Ну и на сайте вопрос пару раз обсуждался, так что старые участники помнят.

Answer (score 3):

Дело в том, что данные в компьютере хранятся в бинарной системе исчесления, а не десятичной.
Поэтому, если вычисления критичные, например работа с деньгами, double или float использовать нельзя.
Для работы с дробями используйте класс BigDecimal .
Или округляйте, если большая точность не важна.
Кстати, это не связано с языком программирования, а скорее с архитектурой процессора и памяти :)

Comment: Это всё-таки не объясняет наблюдаемое поведение.

Comment: Полностью обьясняет. Вот вам более подробное обсуждение этого вопроса на английском: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency

Comment: Хорошо, предположим double иногда выкидывает какой-то хвост. А как тогда хвост отбросить?  Чтобы на ответ не влиял какой-то там эпсилон.

Comment: Ответ не полностью объясняет вопрос. Хотелось бы прояснить, как связана некоторая  ε>0 в хвосте дроби с исходными данными.