# Округление 0,45 до десятых

Tags: c#, .net, математика

Почему команда `>? Math.Round(0.45f, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` возвращает 0.4 , а команда `>? Math.Round(0.45d, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)` 0.5 ?

Команды выполнены в окне команд Visual Studio 2008, версия .Net Framework 3.5

Comment: Подозреваю, что `0.45f != 0.45d` и имеют отклонения в разные стороны от `0.45` от того и разница.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Дело в том, что у 0.45 нет точного представления [в двоичном виде](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/). Это приводит к потерям точности даже там, где разработчик ожидает более точного результата.

В вашем случае происходит upcast float-значения 0.45 к double.

0.45f выглядит примерно так

```
0 01111101      1100 11001100 11001100 110
```

Это примерно `0.449999988079071044921875`.

.NET знает что точность float недостаточна, и при преобразовании в строку использует 7 значащих цифр. `0.4499999 88` отображается как `0.45`. Поэтому и в отладке, и при выводе на консоль вы увидите `0.45`.

0.45d - представляется примерно так:

```
0 0111111 1101  1100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001100 11001101
```

Что примерно равно `0.450000000000000011102230246252`. Для double при преобразовании в строку .NET использует 14 значащих цифр. Значение представляется как `0.45000000000000 00` -> `0.45`

Ок, теперь вы даете процессору 0.45f и просите его сконвертировать его в double. Процессор берет и добивает нулями:

```
0 0111111 1101  1100 11001100 11001100 11000000 00000000 00000000 00000000
```

Что все еще равно  `4.49999988079071044921875`

С точки зрения процессора - точность не пострадала. Но теперь это double, и при операциях с ним предполагается что он достаточно точен, чтобы при работе с ним как с десятичным числом захватить побольше цифр.

Это больше не "примерно `0.45`". Это ведь double. Теперь в нем примерно 14 значащих цифр - значение с точки зрения .NET и процессора превратилось в  "примерно `0.449999988079071`".

Т.е. в двоичном представлении точность не потерялась, в десятичном - тоже - но полученное число теперь отличается от 0.45d, что приводит к округлению в неожиданном направлении.

---

Почему работает аналогичный вызов с приведением к decimal:

```
Math.Round((Decimal)0.45f, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero) // 0.5
```

Приведение в decimal происходит через системный [вызов метода VarDecFromR4](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/775003a4c72f0acc37eab84628fcef541533ba4e/src/palrt/decconv.cpp#L127), который при конвертации округляет float до 7 значащих десятичных цифр, делая из `0.449999988079071044921875` красивое `0.4500000`:

```
// Round the input to a 7-digit integer.  The R4 format has
// only 7 digits of precision, and we want to keep garbage digits
// out of the Decimal were making.
```

Собственно, сам код преобразования (пара экранов) в основном посвящен этому округлению с последующим отрезанием незначащих нулей.

Comment: Для чего же происходит этот upcast? Почему нельзя сразу округлять float?

Comment: Всё понял! просто нет перегрузки Math.Round для float

Comment: @3per: А даже если бы и была — в какую сторону ей округлять `0.449999988079071044921875`? Это не midpoint, это строго меньше середины.

Comment: @VladD, посмотрите код в моём ответе. Если оно строго меньше середины, почему при конвертации в Decimal, округляется "правильно"?

Comment: @3per: Судя по всему, при конвертации в `decimal` произошло округление до в точности 3.45.

Comment: @VladD, ну т.е. вопрос решаем...

Comment: @3per: Или повезло в данном конкретном случае.

Comment: @Vlad, значит мне следует провести исследование...

Comment: Думаю, исследование не нужно. Если вы работаете с плавающей точкой, нет смысла надеяться на попадание в точное значение, вот и всё. А если вам нужны точные десятичные знаки (скорее всего, нет), о нужно отказаться от `double` и пользоваться исключительно `decimal`.

Answer (score 1):

Из
https://stackoverflow.com/a/8240013/5574962
Для того чтобы обойти проблему можно применять такой подход. Такие вычисления, конечно, медленнее.

```
Math.Round((Decimal)0.45f, 1, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)
```

Возвращает `0.5`