# Увеличение целого на вещественный ноль

Tags: java

Имеется следующий код:

```
int i = 2020202048; 
i += 0.0f; 
System.out.println(i);
```

[Выводит:](http://ideone.com/acQBzf)

> 2020201984

Почему?

Comment: видимо приводится к числу с плавающей точкой, при этом разумеется теряется точность ибо числа с плавающей точкой ее не обеспечивают. потом переводится обратно с округлением до ближайшего целого.

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82

Comment: 32-битный float обеспечивает точность около 7 знаков - что выше видимо и происходит.

Comment: Не знаю в чем именно проблема, но это происходит при использовании `float` и операции `+=`. Если [использовать этот код](http://ideone.com/UYz2hD) то можно заметить, что `i2` всегда имеет в последних двух битах число 80.

Comment: @Mike интересно, что `i = i + 0.0f` при этом вовсе не компилируется.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Проблема кроется в составном операторе присваивания `+=`. Согласно [документации](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) исходное выражение `i += 0.0f;` разворачивается в `i = (int)(i + 0.0f);`. Выражение в скобках будет иметь тип `float`, в котором исходное число `2020202048` не имеет точного представления и таким образом изменяется до `2020201984.0f`, которое потом приводится снова к `int`.

Неочевидность кода в вопросе в первую очередь обусловлена именно неявным преобразованием `int` → `float` → `int` (о чем уже упоминалось в комментариях к вопросу), которое происходит при использовании `+=` с разными типами аргументов.