# (x = x + y) или (x += y) — отличия в приведении типов

Tags: java, language-lawyer

Столкнулся с таким вот свойством сложения. У нас есть две переменные:

```
int x = 1;
long y = 2;
```

`y` нужно прибавить к `x`. Если мы воспользуемся простым сложением, то IDE откажется компилировать:

```
x = x + y;    //Incopatible types
```

Если же мы пользуемся следующей конструкцией:

```
x += y;
```

то код обрабатывается корректно.

Ошибка понятна — мы пытаемся запихнуть `long` в `int`, IDE видит потенциальную ошибку и не даёт скомпилировать. Но почему проходит во втором случае?

Comment: [Интересная ситуация по этому поводу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572819/176217).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`var1 op= var2` **равносильно** `var1 = (T)((var1) op (var2))`,
*где op - [оператор](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_basic_operators.htm).*

*Пример:*

```
int x = 2;
double y = 4.6;
```

Данная строка `x += y;` равносильна **нижней**:

```
x = (int)(x + y);
```

Документация: [15.26.2. Compound Assignment Operators](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2)

Comment: И [ссылка на соответствующий раздел JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2).

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev честно говоря недавно читал об этом, правда на другом сайте, и писал по памяти. Но за ссылку спасибо =)

Comment: Хм, неочевидное поведение, в шарпе такого нету, нужно приводить явно. Не совсем понимаю зачем так сделали...

Comment: @Андрей синтаксический сахар =)

Comment: @kxko, больше похоже на синтаксический перец, ибо ведет к ошибкам

Comment: @Андрей из-за такой мелочи, можно провести пару часов выискивая ошибку =)