# Как работает оператор умножения с присваиванием в Java?

Tags: java, операторы

Имеется тестовый кусок кода.

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            int i = 2;
            char c = '1';
            c = (char) c * i; //ошибка компиляции
            System.out.println(c);
    }
}
```

Но

```
...
c *= i; //выводит b
...
```

Почему?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow это другой  вопрос, т.к. здесь идёт речь о преобразовании одного типа в другой. Ниже приведёт правильный ответ, который разница от того вопроса, который вы упомянули.

Comment: Ваш вопрос абсолютно дублирует тот вопрос, который я указал. Разница лишь в типе бинарного оператора - вместо умножения используется сложение.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow мой вопрос заключался в нахождении ошибки компиляции. Я не понимал, как это работает. То, что ответ плавно вытекает из общей спецификации не говорит, что задаваемые вопросы дублируются. Следуя Вашей логике в этом случае, все вопросы на сайте вытекают из основ дискретной математики и их применения. Пометить все вопросы дубликатами и ссылать на учебник по дискретной математике? Слишком утрировал, но смысл понятен.

Comment: Еще один [очень похожий вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/572819/176217).

Comment: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8478/213987

Comment: @AK ну... тогда переоткроем? Данный вопрос затрагивает даже не операторы, а явное и неявное приведение типов при выполнении операторов. `c *= i;` это не явное приведение типов. А `c = (char)(c * i)` - явное.

Comment: @nick_n_a Я бы рекомендовал в подобных случаях собирать пятёрку на переоткрытие из людей обладающих весомой репутацией по java. Свою репутацию по этой метке считаю недостаточной.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Если посмотреть в [спецификацию](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.26.2) то можно увидеть что `E1 op= E2` эквивалентно `E1 = (T) ((E1) op (E2))` где `T` это тип `E1`.

Поэтому

```
 c *= i;
```

из вашего примера эквивалентно

```
c = (char)(c * i);
```

В случае `c = (char)c * i;` проблема в том что оно парсится как `c = ((char)c) * i;` и когда мы умножаем `((char)c)` на `i` результат расширяется до `int`.

Comment: Спасибо! Я разобрался. Но, получается, что присваивание к типу происходит раньше, ежели операция умножения?