# Java. При вычитании из типа float типа int выводится некорректный результат

Tags: java

```
package com.veselllov;

public class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args){
    int a = 1;
    double b = 4.6;

    System.out.println(a - b);
  }
}
```

На выходе: 
-3.5999999999999996

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Числа с плавающей точкой не являются точными, так как не все числа могут быть точно выражены через степень двойки.

Если Вам нужны точные результаты, можете воспользоваться классом `BigDecimal`.

Подробнее [здесь](https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/) и [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/220996).