# Как компьютер суммирует ряды?

Tags: процесс

Подскажите пожалуйста как компьютер суммирует  плохо сходящиеся ряды. У него конечная точность вычислений, и если прибавлять члены которые много меньше текущей суммы ряда, то точности может не хватить. Т.е. компьютер не сможет прибавить одну миллиардную к сумме членов  которую он уже посчитал. И при дальнейшем суммировании будет выдавать один и тот же результат.

Comment: он суммирует их ровно так, как Вы его научите.

Comment: При нынешней цене на память, вряд ли встанет задача, когда может не хватить точности.

Comment: Вам наверняка будет интересен вот этот вопрос: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для "плохо сходящихся" рядов нужно использовать специальные алгоритмы расчёта.

Простейший алгоритм - это расчёт суммы блоков элементов и последующее суммирование сумм этих блоков. Размер блока выбирается так, чтобы при расчёте его суммы потери точности были минимальны (например, начинать новый блок, когда порядок очередного члена уменьшится по сравнению с предыдущим). Хорошо работает для монотонных рядов, но плохо для знакопеременных, для которых этот алгоритм модифицируют, считая отдельно блоки чётных и нечётных элементов.

Само собой суммирование сумм блоков выполняют от меньших к бОльшим.

Answer (score 1):

Если стоит задача не потерять точность, то следует использовать соответствующие типы/библиотеки. Например для python точность для Decimal ограничена только оперативной памятью (по умолчанию 28 знаков):

```
from decimal import Decimal

s = Decimal(0)
s += Decimal(100000000000000)
s += Decimal(0.0000000000001)
print (s)
```

> 100000000000000.0000000000001

[Живой пример](https://repl.it/En1Y/2).

Comment: насчёт цены на память: знакомые занимаются моделированием океанов, там в ходу умножение кубических матриц порядка 1000х1000х1000. Вроде неплохо так памяти требует. ))

Comment: Насчёт классов: а как внутри устроен Decimal? Он хранит число, как строку?

Comment: @NickVolynkin Ну с учетом того, что есть быстрые SSD, такая матрица наверное не проблема, хотя согласен, есть задачи где затык в объемах данных. На счет хранения не в курсе, тип встроенный, наверное от реализации зависит. Хотя я бы не стал в виде строки хранить (слишком расточительно), может быть что-то вроде long (который берет столько байтов, сколько нужно под хранение числа) + позицию запятой.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, формат хранения DECIMAL описывается стандартом IEEE 754. Им установлены три варианта - Decimal32,  Decimal64 и  Decimal128. Если интересуют подробности, лучше читать сам стандарт - там ну очень много текста...

Comment: @Akina, спасибо. Vladimir, предлагаю добавить ссылку: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point#Basic_and_interchange_formats

Comment: @NickVolynkin, Akina ребзя, речь про питон, у него decimal безразмерный. И в других языках есть подобные фишки (в виде внешних библиотек). Меседж был в том, что один из вариантов - использовать подходящие типы/библиотеки, которые предотвратят потерю точности.