# Ошибка в pascal с числами с двумя знаками после запятой

Tags: pascal

У меня есть генератор чисел с двумя знаками после запятой

```
a:= random(10)+0.03-5;
b:= random(10)+0.06-5;
```

Но иногда с данными значениями выдается вот такой пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Часто бывает что ответ к примеру 5.91, но за правильный ответ компьютер считает 5.9
Собственно этот ответ компьютер получает так

```
c:=a+b;
```

и потом сравнивает

```
if (otvet=c) then

      begin
      writeln ('Правильно!');
```

Как можно ограничить программу от генерации таких чисел как на скриншоте? И что можно сделать с проблемой округления?

Comment: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82

Comment: Вы бы еще хуже скриншот привели, а то с лупой и вывернутой яркостью таки что-то можно увидеть. Непорядок...