# В чем разница между float и double в Java?

Tags: java, типы-данных

Насколько я помню, *float* и *double* различаются диапазонами, что ведёт к разной точности и скорости вычислений. Однако сегодня заметил, что с разными числами округление происходит у этих типов данных по-разному.
На скринах видно, что

- в первом случае *float* обрубает значение, а *double* округляет
  ([example1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6QlC.jpg))
- Во втором случае: *float* округляет, *double* обрубает
  значение([example2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I1I5p.jpg))

Какая еще есть разница между типами данных *float* и *double* или я что-то в упор не вижу?

Comment: Вставляйте код прямо в сообщение (в виде кода), а не ссылайтесь на внешние ресурсы. Сообщения должны быть самодостаточными, ссылки могут служить только дополнением.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Принципиальный нюанс здесь в том, что вы оперируете десятичными числами, а float и double — бинарные. Те числа, которые вы делите и получаете в результате, *непредставимы* в бинарной системе счисления без периодичных дробей. Подробнее:

**[Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)**

То, что вы наблюдаете — это не округления и обрубания, а попытки компьютера впихать невпихуемое и сделать вид, что на самом деле всё в порядке. Так как количество битов у мантиссы и экспоненты типов float и double разная, то "округления" и "обрубания" будут происходить с вашей точки зрения "непредсказуемо". Эта ситуация усугубляется ещё и тем, что точность вычислений на совести процессора, который, вообще говоря, не обязан выдавать точность до последнего знака. На другом компьютере вы можете увидеть другие результаты — если не включите специальный "предсказуемый" режим, который медленнее. Но даже в этом случае вы получите только одинаковые, но "непредсказуемые" результаты на разных компьютерах.

Когда работаете с float и double, примите как данность, что они всегда с погрешностью.