# Округление чисел до ближайшего меньшего по модулю значения

Tags: c#

Как можно округлить число до ближайшего меньшего по модулю значения в C#. Например в Excel для этого есть формула =ОКРУГЛВНИЗ(число;число разрядов).

Например, округлить число 1 545 978, 80 -> 1 545 000,00

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ef48waz8(v=vs.110).aspx MidpointRounding

Comment: @AK, посмотри как именно он хочет _округлять_

Comment: @Grundy Кстати, да. Топикстартер, а вам нужно до ближайшего целого округлять верно? Ну, и чтобы два раза не вставать: отрицательные числа могут быть, если да, то у них правило округления будет в сторону минус бесконечности?

Comment: До ближайшего меньшего по модулю.  Числа только положительные. Просто получается вот что. У меня есть написанная программа, там есть сумма, которая при расчете принимает значение double, но можно и целое число выводить. Так вот сумма например может быть как в примере 1 545 978 рублей. А на в документе мне надо указать уже  1 545 000. Сейчас это делается в Excel, но оттуда мы уходим в софт.

Comment: Вы не должны считать деньги в `double`, никогда-никогда. Для финансовых расчётов используется **исключительно** `decimal`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Встроенной функции, выполняющей данное действие, нет. Но всегда можно написать свою, например:

```
double roundDown(double number, int p)
{
    return Math.Round(number - number % Math.Pow(10, p));
}
```

Пример вызова

```
 roundDown(1545978.80, 3) // 1545000.0
```

---

#### Как это работает?

Пусть начальное число `1545978.80` и надо получить `1545000.00`

Для получения из исходного числа надо вычесть `978.80`.

Это является остатком от деления исходного числа на 1000, что в свою очередь является 10<sup>3</sup>, где `3` - это количество нулей перед запятой.

Comment: То что нужно и это работает. Можете рассказать, если не сложно как работает return Math.Round(number - number % Math.Pow(10, p)); Уже целый день пытаюсь придумать, еще только учусь программировать....уже голова не варит.

Comment: @AndreySherman, дополнил ответ, но советую прислушаться к совету [@VladD](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/694133/%d0%9e%d0%ba%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%bb-%d0%b4%d0%be-%d0%b1%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b6%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c%d1%88%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8e-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f/694186#comment1027528_694133)

Answer (score 1):

Десятичные знаки имеют смысл только для чисел типа `decimal`, для чисел типа `double` понятие десятичного разряда [бессмысленно](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/10105).

Для обыкновенного округления (`Round`) есть такая функция «из коробки»: [`Decimal.Round(Decimal, Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6be1edhb(v=vs.110).aspx).

Но для округления вниз вам придётся писать самостоятельно:

```
static decimal Truncate(decimal d, int places) =>
    Shift(Math.Truncate(Shift(d, places)), -places);

static decimal Shift(decimal d, int places)
{
    if (places >= 0)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < places; i++)
            d /= 10m;
    }
    else
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < -places; i++)
            d *= 10m;
    }
    return d;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public double Floor(double num, int rank)
{
  if (rank == 0)
    return Math.Truncate(num);

  num /= Math.Pow(10, -rank);
  num = Math.Truncate(num);
  num *= Math.Pow(10, -rank);

  return num;
}
```

Comment: это не то, что просил автор

Comment: Почему тогда не просто `Math.Truncate`?

Comment: Math.Truncate отрезает все до запятой т.е. 10,5 будет 10.

Comment: @AndreySherman: Комментарий относился к [старой редакции ответа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/revisions/694155/1).

Comment: Как я понял вы отталкиваетесь от функции [ОКРУГЛВНИЗ в Excel](https://support.office.com/ru-ru/article/%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%97-%D1%84%D1%83%D0%BD%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%9E%D0%9A%D0%A0%D0%A3%D0%93%D0%9B%D0%92%D0%9D%D0%98%D0%97-2ec94c73-241f-4b01-8c6f-17e6d7968f53). Прогнал код через тесты, вроде все работает как надо,в том числе с отрицательным ranke

Answer (score 0):

Пробробуйте поиграть с Math.Floor(...), Math.Ceiling(...), Math.Round(...)

```
public string down(double number, int digit) {
    var a = number;
    a /= Math.Pow(10, digit);
    a = Math.Round(a, 0);
    a *= Math.Pow(10, digit);;
    return $"{a},00";
}
```

Что-то вроде этого. Кривовато, но вашу задачу выполняет. Думаю стоит копать в эту сторону.

Comment: Round(double Число, int КоличествоРазрядов, MidpointRounding), Round(decimal Число, int КоличествоРазрядов, MidpointRounding) — округляет указанное число до указанного числа десятичных разрядов после запятой. Третий аргумент задает правила округления если значение находится ровно посередине между двумя числами и может принимать значения:
MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero - до ближайшего числа в сторону большего по модулю значения; А меньшего пока не нашел( Надо играться... Единственный вариант в голову еще пришел это string.Format();

Comment: Я бы пошёл через алгоритм: сперва разделил бы число на 10^число десятков. Этим бы запятая ушла влево. Дальше округли все после запятой до нуля. И умножил бы на 10^чисдо десятков. Добавив этим нужное количество нулей. С телефона не удобно дома буду напишу уже на языке

Answer (score 0):

Почему не разделить  и не умножить на тоже самое?? очевидно вроде... привести к целому,
123456789 / 1000 = 123456,  далее 123456 * 1000 получим исходное округленное вниз =123456000 привести к плавающему, если именно 00 после запятой нужно.
И вообще 1545978.80 сильно на UNIX время похоже,

Comment: Добро пожаловать на StackOverflow на русском! Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что не стоит писать комментарии в поле "Ответ". У вас есть некоторое направление, но нет точного кода - это скорее признак того, что это не полноценное решение, а ремарка на полях, замечание. Также не совсем понятно, откуда взялось магическое число 1000, на которое вы предлагаете умножать... Как-то неуниверсально, а если бы после запятой были бы другие числа - коэффициент нужен будет другой? Какая-то связь есть между этой магией и "число разрядов"?

Comment: Почему магическое?? во первых на сколько надо округлить, на столько и делим. Надо все кратно тысяче?? или  сколько нужно там.. мне надо было "округлять" кратно  и 15 и 10_000, разделил ,  умножил - все число получено у топик стартера именно вопрос: ,Например, округлить число 1 545 978, 80 -> 1 545 000,00   =  (1 545 978, 80 /1000 ) * 1000 = 1 545 000 ,если еще нужно именно  еще 2 ( или больше) знака  после запятой - в С# придется  далее преобразовать в тип decimal,  иначе в  doubl`e и float`e  будут ползать последние цифры.. пр 15,8500000001. или 12,000000001 ( за точность знаков уж простити)