# Как перевести десятичную дробь в обычную?

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм, математика

Пример: Получая на входе 0.2 получить 1/5.  Использование специальных библиотек не рассматривается.

Comment: Вот кстати числа, которые в виде десятичной дроби достаточно просто выглядят (например 0.1, 0.2) в двоичном виде - бесконечные периодические дроби, поэтому преобразовать из double в обыкновенную дробь "правильно" (т.е. например 0.2 -> 1/5) будет довольно проблематично.

Comment: @insolor а вдруг к топикастера decimal!

Comment: @PashPash, если не указано, значит не определено (может и decimal, а может и double). Возможно вам стоит написать свой ответ?)

Comment: @insolor его уже написал Harry - его ответ отлично работает для decimal

Comment: @PashaPash: Для double тоже работает, только в знаменателе будет степень двойки. Ну и понятно, что `(double)0.1` не даст 1/10.

Comment: @VladD даже остановившиеся часы показывают точное время, но только дважды в сутки :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример кода на C# через разбиение строки на целую и дробную часть, могут быть пролемы при больших дробях если не будут влазить в long.

```
    static string DoubleToNormalFraction(double numeric)
    {
        //Разбиваем число на целую и дробную часть
        var numericArray = numeric.ToString().Split(new[] { CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator }, StringSplitOptions.None);
        var wholeStr = numericArray[0];
        var fractionStr = "0";
        if (numericArray.Length > 1)
            fractionStr = numericArray[1];

        //Получаем степень десятки, на которую нужно умножить число, чтобы дробь стала целым 
        var power = fractionStr.Length;

        //Получаем целую часть числителя и знаменатель
        long whole = long.Parse(wholeStr) * 10;
        long denominator = 10;
        for (int i = 1; i < power; i++)
        {
            denominator = denominator * 10;
            whole = whole * 10;
        }

        //получаем числитель
        var numerator = long.Parse(fractionStr);
        numerator = numerator + whole;


        //Ищем общий знаменатель и делим на него
        var index = 2; 
        while(index < denominator/2) //Если дошли до половины, то там его нет. Тут вообще можно брать наименьшее из числителя и знаменателя
        {
            if(numerator % index == 0 && denominator % index == 0)
            {
                numerator = numerator / index;
                denominator = denominator / index;
                index = 1; //При i++ будет увеличен до 2х
            }
            index++;
        }

        return $"{numerator}/{denominator}";
    }
```

Comment: А если на входе будет получено целое число? Ну и для поиска НОД кошернее алгоритм Эвклида

Comment: Если на вход придет целое число, то fractionStr = "0";

Answer (score 8):

Если вы точно знаете десятичную дробь - т.е. например, что это именно 0.2, а не 0.19999999999876 :), то записывайте ее как обычную умножением на 10 в соответствующей степени (0.2 = 2/10), находите НОД числителя и знаменателя, и приводите ее к несократимому виду делением и числителя, и знаменателя на НОД...

Comment: "Если вы точно знаете десятичную дробь" - дальше можно не читать.

Comment: @Igor почему вы считаете, что в C# / .NET нет точного представления для 0.2?

Comment: @PashaPash, (перебегая из другого треда) может ответ и работает для decimal, но тогда стоило бы упомянуть в ответе этот тип данных. Я вот например про него не знал, может и автор вопроса не знает.

Comment: @insolor ok. автору вопроса и будущим читателям - double в .net дает [приблизительное значение для большинства десятичных дробей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/177221). Вместо double для точных вычислений (и особенно для представления в коде денег!) стоит использовать тип [decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/decimal).

Comment: @PashaPash Да мало ли в каком виде это число задано - может, это просто вводимая пользователем строка?...

Comment: @Harry, более того, если у нас число, то мы можем его перевести в строку (в нужном формате и с нужной точностью) и затем безболезненно найти положение десятичной точки, распарсить числитель и вычислить число знаков знаменателя дроби

Comment: @Harry я вообще-то отвечал Igor-у, который, судя по всему, считал что в C# вообще нет точного представления для десятичных дробей. А на длинном предупреждении про double настоял insolor - так что все вопросы к нему :)

Comment: @Андрей "нужная точность" подразумевает, что переводить в дробь вы будете не оригинальное число, а какое-то другое.