# Округление double или точность

Tags: java, double

Есть такая запись. В ней создается класс с значениями 1 и 100 и потом проверяется, действительно ли он создался с такими значениями. Как называется вот это - 1.0, 0.001?  Это что то типа округления видимо. Хотелось бы узнать название и почитать про такой способ записи числа double. 100.0, 0.001 - аналогично.

```
@Test
public void shouldCreateInterval() {
    Interval interval = new Interval(1.0, 100.0);
    assertEquals(interval.getFrom().doubleValue(), 1.0, 0.001);
    assertEquals(interval.getTo().doubleValue(), 100.0, 0.001);
}
```

Comment: 1.0 это само число, с которым сравнивают,  0.001 - допустимая погрешность.

Comment: Почему так - см. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/Вычисления-на-числах-с-плавающей-точкой-не-работают

Comment: Как это правильно называется в java, чтоб можно было почитать про использование погрешности? Не теорию а синтаксис.

Comment: Допустим, его называют epsilon. Все его использование заключается в сравнении чисел с плавающей точкой. Из-за особенностей, описанных по ссылке выше, проверка на равенство выглядит так: `Math.abs(expected - actual) < epsilon`

Comment: Очень хорошая статья про плавающую точку https://habrahabr.ru/post/337260/

Comment: Вопрос в том где описан сам синтаксис 1.0 , 0.001?

Comment: Проверка на равенство при заданной точности

Comment: Это не особенность конкретно Java, а вещественных чисел в двоичном представлении.

Comment: Это не синтаксис и не способ записи числа. Это второй и третий параметры функции проверки равенства.

Comment: Понятно. И синтаксис нашел- assertEquals(double expected, double actual, double delta)