# (long)Math.pow(299792458,2) возвращает неверное число

Tags: java

При попытке возведения в квадрат значения *с* (скорость света) выводится неверное число.

Должно быть:

> 89875517873681764

Для `(long)Math.pow(c, 2)` выводится:

> 89875517873681760

В чем проблема?

Comment: `c` то чему равно?

Comment: @Suvitruf сказано же, скорость света (физическая величина). Она в заголовке вопроса выдана.

Comment: Возможно дело в округлений - там же вычисления в типе Double.

Comment: Связанный вопрос: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/181100)

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как принятый ^_^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Math.pow` работает с типом `double`. Отсюда и ошибка округления.

Хотите получить `89875517873681764`, работайте с типом `long`:

```
    long c = 299792458;
    long pow2 = c * c;
```

Comment: Ещё как вариант можно использовать `BigInteger` или `BigDecimal`: `BigInteger.valueOf(c).pow(2).longValue()`.