# Operator '||' cannot be applied to java.lang.Double

Tags: java, junit

Что не так?

```
Double first_side = (Double) parameters.get(0);
Double second_side = (Double) parameters.get(1);
Double third_side = (Double) parameters.get(2);

assertTrue((first_side = Math.sqrt(second_side * second_side + third_side * third_side)) ||
           (second_side = Math.sqrt(first_side * first_side + third_side * third_side)) ||
           (third_side = Math.sqrt(first_side * first_side + second_side * second_side))
);
```

Comment: не путайте присваивание `=` и сравнение `==` :)

Comment: Сравнение тут тоже не сработает =)

Comment: @lDrakonl, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/176064

Comment: `Что не так?` Операция "логического или" не может быть применена к Double

Comment: @lDrakonl, мы про java говорим? `||` определена только для булевых типов

Comment: @Nati если какой нибудь ответ отвечает на ваш вопрос, вы нажмите "принять ответ"

Answer (score 6):

Для сравнения значений надо использовать `==`, а не `=`. Код будет таким:

```
assertTrue((first_side == Math.sqrt(second_side * second_side + third_side * third_side)) ||
           (second_side == Math.sqrt(first_side * first_side + third_side * third_side)) ||
           (third_side == Math.sqrt(first_side * first_side + second_side * second_side))
);
```

Однако, не смотря на то, что код будет компилироваться, **результат работы может отличаться от ожидаемого**. 
Из за плавающей запятой сравнение двух одинаковых чисел `double` на равенство может возвращать `false`.
Подробнее в вопросе [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/176064)

Answer (score 1):

Ваша проблема в том, что нельзя логическую операцию выполнить над числами, логические операции выполняются на  boolean(false,true). 
Функция **assertTrue** принимает boolean переменную, вы же пытаетесь туда засунуть double.