# Функция МАТЕМАТИЧЕСКОГО округления. Есть ли проще?

Tags: delphi, математика

Нашел функцию которая делает МАТЕМАТИЧЕСКОЕ округление числа.
Чуть доработав ее до округления отрицательных чисел.

```
function MathRound(AValue: double; 
          APrecision: integer): double; 
var 
  db, db1, db2: double; 
  i: int64; 
  ii, ink, i1, LTypeNumber: integer; 
begin 
  begin
    if AValue < 0 then
      LTypeNumber := 0
    else LTypeNumber := 1;
    AValue := Abs(AValue);
  end;

  db := AValue-int(AValue); 
  ink := 1; 
  for ii := 1 to APrecision 
    do ink := ink*10; 
  db1 := db*ink; 
  db2 := AValue*ink*100; 
  i := trunc(int(db2)/100); 
  i1 := trunc(db2-i*100); 
  if i1 > 49 then 
    inc(i); 
  if LTypeNumber = 0 then
    result := -1*(i/ink)
  else result := i/ink;
end;
```

Возможно есть более простое решение…
Выдающее следующий результат (округление например до тысячных):

```
3,6145 = 3,615
3,6045 = 3,615
4,6445 = 4,645
2,3145 = 2.315
```

Все другие стандартные функции рассчитаны на банковское округление – мне не подходит.
Например если взять "SimpleRoundTo(4.6445, -3)" то это будет = 4.644

Comment: Округление чисел с плавающей запятой не до целого лишено смысла, т. к. десятичные дроби не могут быть представлены точно типом `double`.

Comment: Ну а всетаки, мне просто нужно выдержать нужное количество разрядов после запятой и правильное отображение последнего из них.

Comment: Ну, корректное решение — это пользоваться не двоичными дробями, типа `double`, а десятичными. Дело в том, что число наподобие `0.1` в принципе невозможно точно представить в виде `double`. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/10105

Comment: @VladD Дело говорит. Как вариант умножить на 1000 округлить через round() превратить в целое число. Только оно будет в 1000 раз больше.... :(

Answer (score 2):

В школе учили округлять до 3-х знаков после запятой таким методом:

```
Int(AValue * 1000 + 0.5 * Sign(AValue))/1000
```

Превратить APrecision в множитель/делитель, думаю сами сможете.

Answer (score 0):

Да, пока остановился пока на функции (из пакета того же "**[by John Herbster](http://cc.embarcadero.com/Item.aspx?id=21909)** "), если кому интересно:
например,
Код:

> DecimalRoundDbl(-2,3145, 3, drHalfUp);

математическое округление

Answer (score 0):

Используй SimpleRoundTo из модуля Math

```
function SimpleRoundTo(const AValue: Extended; const ADigit: TRoundToRange = -2): Extended;
var
  LFactor: Extended;
begin
  LFactor := IntPower(10, ADigit);
  if AValue < 0 then
    Result := Trunc((AValue / LFactor) - 0.5) * LFactor
  else
    Result := Trunc((AValue / LFactor) + 0.5) * LFactor;
end;
```