# Непонятный результат при системном разделителе «точка»

Tags: delphi, архитектура, double, cpu

Доброе время суток,
поменял в Windows 10 системный `DecimalSeparator` с `,` на `.`

И проверил следующий вариант, который немного не понял: почему выдает `false`, если `q=0.01`?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для правильного отрабатывания  этого примера пришлось написать следующую, функцию например:

```
function TFMain.RETURN_VALUE(ANumber: double):double;
begin
  Result := ANumber;
end;

procedure TFMain.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  q: double;
begin
  q := 0.02 - 0.01;
  if q = RETURN_VALUE(0.01) then
    showmessage('=')
  else showmessage('><')  ;
end;
```

которая выдает правильный результат (системный разделитель оставил «запятую»).

Можно ли проще?

Comment: Ваш код никаким образом не зависит от того, какой в Windows установлен десятичный разделитель.

Comment: Данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что он вызван совершенно другой причиной, чем описываемая.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Не важно, что вы используете в качестве разделителя десятичных знаков, важно правильно сравнивать вещественные числа из-за особенностей их реализации в железе (Дональд Кнут 2 том, 4 глава, если я не ошибаюсь, хорошо описывает эти тонкости, но можно найти и в [сети](https://ru.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C)). Вот такой код:

```
Uses System.Math;
<...> 
procedure TForm2.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    var
      q: double;
    begin
      q := 0.02 - 0.01;
      if SameValue(q, 0.01) then
        showmessage('=')
      else showmessage('><')  ;
    end;
```

выдаст вам равенство. Функция `SameValue`, которая описывается как

```
function SameValue(const A, B: Extended[; Epsilon: Extended]): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Double[; Epsilon: Double]): Boolean; overload;
function SameValue(const A, B: Single[; Epsilon: Single]): Boolean; overload;
```

очень полезна ещё и тем, что позволяет сравнить два числа в эпсилон-окрестности. Поэтому, если вы проводите математические расчёты, используйте `SameValue` именно с указанием необходимого значения `Epsilon`, что даст вам желаемую точность. Если же `Epsilon` не указать или указать нулевым, то он будет высчитан автоматически по данной формуле: `Epsilon = Max(Min(Abs(A), Abs(B)) * 1E-12, 1E-12)`

Comment: А можно узнать, какой Эпсилон по умолчанию?

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov ЕМНИП, для разных типов разное, для double - 1E-12

Comment: Я бы ещё рекомендовал почитать [эту статью](https://habrahabr.ru/post/112953/), если действительно интересно разобраться.

Comment: @Alekcvp Да, статья нормальная, но в ней, минимум, половина как раз из Кнута :) А Кнут - must be read!

Comment: @AlexeyKozlov эпсилон - это не обязательный параметр, так что если вы не знаете какой он должен быть, просто не указывайте его и будет использовано значение по умолчанию.

Comment: Я думал, что только при делении чисел с плавающей точкой возникают проблемы с представлением/вычислением. Оказывается ни какая операция не застрахована от ошибок над ними.