# sql и dbgrd delphi не корректное отображение данных

Tags: sql-server, delphi-7, dbgrid

Создал в sql-server таблицу в тип значение поставил real. В delphi создал dbgrd подключил к таблице при добавлении данных например "0,153" на dbgrd  отображается "0,152999997138977" как мне это исправить подскажите пожалуйста.

[image: таблица sql-server]

[image: отображение в sql-server]

[image: отображение в delphi]

изменил тип на decimal(18, 0) но при добавлении данных отображается "0"

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Вы задавали себе вопрос, "что означают цифры в скобках в выражении `decimal(18, 0)`"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это нормально. Взгляните для объяснения, к примеру, на [этот топик](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/761255/). Судя по всему, вы собираетесь хранить в этом поле деньги или курс денег. В этом случае лучше используйте `Decimal`, этот формат гораздо лучше подходит для хранения суммы денег.

Comment: изменил тип на decimal(18, 0) но при добавлении данных отображается "0"

Comment: @delphi формат decimal(18, 0), поразумевает 18 знаков и 0 знаков после запятой справа, под "0,153" вам необходим decimal(18, 3), ну и можете на свое усмотрение указывать общую длинну (18).

Comment: все заработало всем  спасибо за помощь и еще в типе указал nvarchar(100) тоже заработало.