# При преобразовании String с дробными числами теряется информация

Tags: java

Столбец excel содержит числа в диапазоне от 1 до 0.0001.
Когда оператор в ручную делает суммирование стобца примерно из 10-30 строк получается число 15,028

Я делаю автоматизацию. Мне в программу приходят данные из БД ОРАКЛ.
Информация приходит в виде строк. Я преобразую строки в тип Double и суммирую.
Сумма тех же строк дает у меня 13,9

Может ли Double округлять значения из-за чего информация теряется и как с этим бороться?

```
for (String[] rowx : СписокмассивовстрокИзОракл) {
            String key = "комбинация данных по логике автоматизации";
            try {
                if (mapMass.containsKey(key)) {
                    try {
                        double src = 0.0;
                        try {
                            src = Double.valueOf(rowx[timeFakt]); //косяк, данные хранящиеся в ячейке timeFakt могут быть типа 0,0028 или 0,0000034. и они округляются.
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        total = Double.valueOf(mapMassTwo.get(key)) + src;
                        String tf = String.valueOf(total);
                        mapMassTwo.put(key, tf);
                        total = 0.0;
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } else {
                    String tf = rowx[timeFakt];
                    mapMass.put(key, tf );
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: Excel суммирует не то, что показывает, а реальные значения типа double с которыми работает внутри. Показывает он уже округленные значения.

Comment: @Padawan "Пара десятков строк" - и погрешность 15%? Что-то здесь не то. Покажите код и данные. Желательно также записать, какие числа у Вас получаются из этих строк.

Comment: @Igor до 50% погрешность суммы при работе с округленными значениями вполне может быть: 1.4 + 1.4 = 2.8 округляем - 3, то же с предварительным округлением слагаемых даст 1 + 1 = 2, вот вам и 50% погрешности на ровном месте.

Comment: @rdorn Такое, конечно, возможно, но автор пишет, о результате с дробной частью, поэтому мне кажется, что в вопросе не вся информация.

Comment: @Igor информации конечно мало, хотя бы пример исходных данных нужен, на котором такое получается. Но меня смущает именно то, что данные приходят в виде строк - excel не показывает настоящие цифры с которыми работает, их у него можно только через interop-Api забрать, и то не факт

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, вполне. Операции с числами с плавающей точкой могут приводить к потерям. Вы можете использовать `BigDecimal`:

```
BigDecimal sum = new BigDecimal(0);

while (thereIsNumbers()) {
    BigDecimal number = new BigDecimal(getNextNumberAsStringFromExcel());
    sum = sum.add(number);
}

System.out.println(sum);
```

При создании `BigDecimal` важно передавать в конструктор именно строку. Если вы передадите туда представление вашей строки уже в виде `double`, то могут быть погрешности.

Немного про погрешности: https://habrahabr.ru/post/219595/

Comment: Да это решило проблему!

Comment: BigDecimal будет наверное память кушать да?

Comment: @Padawan Определенно, памяти будет использовано больше, чем для обычной `double`. [Тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2501176/java-bigdecimal-memory-usage) описаны все внутренние переменные, в которых хранится состояние `BigDecimal`. Однако если ваш код работает примерно так, как я описал, то каждую итерацию цикла будет создаваться новый `BigDecimal`, а старые (по возможности) будут собираться `GC`. И если вам не нужно работать с миллионами таких переменных, то вам нечего бояться. И вообще, `String`-представление числа ведь не меньше занимает)