# Неточный результат при вычислении числа Каталана

Tags: python, python-3.x, числовые-последовательности

В чем может быть проблема при просчете чисел Каталана? На больших числах возникает неточность, т.е на 45 числе выводит 2257117854077247679365120, а должно быть 2257117854077248073253720.

```
arr = [1]
def Catalan(n):
    global arr
    while(len(arr) != n+1):
        arr.append(int(int(arr[len(arr)-1] ) * (4*len(arr)-2)/(len(arr)+1) ) )
    print(arr[n])
```

Comment: А какой тип используется в Питоне для работы с числами, Double какой-нибудь, с точностью до 18 знаков?

Comment: @Kromster, если тут всё целочисленное, он должен сам перейти на biginteger. Про дробные не знаю.

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, судя по меткам питон третий, но там есть деление: `(4*len(arr)-2)/(len(arr)+1)`.

Comment: Пролистал документацию, написано, что с третьей версии int не имеет границ, а использовал при написании 3.5.

Comment: def Catalan(n): arr = [1] for j in range(1,n+1): total = [] for i in range(j): final = arr[i]*arr[j-1-i] total.append(final) fin = sum(total) arr.append(fin) print(arr[n]) Вот такой код. Деления нет, но все равно при числе 45 выводит ложный результат. В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 9):

```
(4*len(arr)-2)/(len(arr)+1) )
#             ^ вот поэтому
```

В Python 3 `/` выполняет деление с плавающей точкой. А точность двойных чисел с плавающей точкой ограничена примерно 15-17 десятичными цифрами, аккурат после которых (15) у вас и наблюдается разница.

См. также ["Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают"](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/181100)

```
1 / 1 # => 1.0
```

Если заменить его на `//`, целочисленное деление (которое в Python 2 выполнялось оператором `/`, если операнды были целочисленными), результаты станут ожидаемыми. Поэтому, кстати, этот алгоритм прекрасно работает в Python 2 (если не импортировать "деление из будущего").

---

И выкиньте `int(...)`'ы. Там и так будут целые числа.

Answer (score 1):

Удобнее реализовывать подобные функции по рекурентным формулам, например если взять [третью рекурентную формулу из википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%9A%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B0), получим следующую функцию:

```
import functools


@functools.lru_cache(maxsize=None)
def catalan(n):
    if n == 0:
        return 1
    return catalan(n-1)*2*(2*n-1)//(n+1)
```

Результат для 45:
2257117854077248073253720

Comment: `lru_cache` следовало бы добавить.

Comment: Если требуется вычислить одно число, то думаю нет необходимости, так как повторных вычислений не будет. А так да, хорошее дополнение.

Comment: каждое `catalan(n-1)` будет вычислять `n` до `n == 0`.

Comment: точно, затупил)