# JSON неверно сохраняет значения переменных типа float

Tags: c#, json, unity3d, сериализация

Сериализирую объект при помощи JsonUtility. Вот что выходит:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

А вот как должно быть:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Собственно, вот и вся проблема :)
Есть идеи?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: @AntonShchyrov причина там описана, а вот способа решения проблемы в контексте сериализации json там нету

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JSON сохраняет правильно.

Дело в том, что значение `0.2` [не представимо](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/10105) точно ни в типе `float`, ни в типе `double` (поскольку не является двоичной дробью). JSON переводит значения в тип `double`, и получаются именно такие значения.

Проверка: https://ideone.com/TUXPL7

Заставить JSON сохранять во `float` невозможно, т. к. в JSON есть только `double`.

---

Если хотите «красивый» вывод, пусть в вашей программе будут значения типа `double`: `0.2`, а не `0.2f`. `0.2f` при приведении к `double` не даёт `0.2`, ничего поделать нельзя. Или форматируйте самостоятельно через `string.Format` или `f.ToString("0.##")`.

Comment: Это мне и так понятно, однако хотелось бы иметь красивые значения в файле без всяких ошибок точности

Comment: @grenqa: Когда вы присваиваете числу типа `float` или `double` значение `0.2`, вы **уже** допускаете ошибку точности. Число 0.2 **не представимо** в виде `double`.

Comment: @grenqa: Попробуйте вот такой простой код: `double d = 0.2; Console.WriteLine(d * 64 - 12);`.

Comment: Мне прекрасно известно как работают типы float и double, я просто хочу получить красивые числа в json файле, чтобы с ними было приятно работать

Comment: @grenqa: Вы хотите, чтобы запоминались неправильные значения? Красивые = неправильные. Ну или переходите на `double` вместо `float`, если красивые значения вам реально важны.

Comment: Спасибо вам. Перешёл на double, всё работает, числа красивые

Comment: @grenqa: Рад, что помогло! Числа с плавающей запятой — достаточно сложная тема с неприятными сюрпризами.