# Цикл не выдает правильный результат

Tags: c++

Всех приветствую, вот код

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
double c = 0.1;
for(double x = c; x < 5;x+=c){
    for(double y = c;y < 5;y += c){
        if((x+y == 5.0)&&(x*x + y*y > 13) ){
            std::cout << "x = " << x << "  y = " << y << std::endl;
            std::cout << x*x*x*x*x + y*y*y*y*y << std::endl;
        }
    }
}

return 0;
}
```

Этот код ищет пары значений х и у, при которых выполняется условие `(x+y == 5.0)&&(x*x + y*y > 13)`. Если с == 1, то он выдаст значения 1 и 4, что логично и удовлетворяет условию. Если же с == 0.1, то он выдаст х = 0.5, у = 4.5, что также удовлетворяет условию, но он почему-то не выводит значения х = 1 и у = 4, хотя они также вроде как должны попасться при прохождении цикла.

Если же с == 0.01, то он вообще ничего не выводит, хотя должен вывести несколько значений, в которые попадут и значения при с = 0.1 и при с = 1. В общем, не знаю, где моя ошибка в коде. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Значение `0.1` не представимо точно в двоичной плавающей арифметике на вашей платформе. `x` в вашем цикле никогда не принимает значение `1`, `y` никогда не принимает значение `4`, а `x + y` никогда не становится равным `5`. Потому вы их и не видите.

Либо делайте сравнение с допуском, либо пользуйтесь арифметикой с фиксированной точностью

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  int c = 1;
  for (int x = c; x < 50; x += c) {
    for (int y = c; y < 50; y += c) {
        if (x + y == 50 && x*x + y*y > 1300) {
            std::cout << "x = " << (double) x / 10 << "  y = " << (double) y / 10 << std::endl;
            std::cout << (double) (x*x*x*x*x + y*y*y*y*y) / 100000 << std::endl;
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Вместо 0.1 возьмите 0.125, и все получится.

Answer (score 3):

Поскольку числа с плавающей точкой абсолютно точно представить в двоичном виде нельзя (например, то же значение 0.1 на самом деле хранится как примерно 0.10000000000000000555) - то и сравнение на равенство обычно не срабатывает.

Попробуйте такой код и посмотрите на результаты:

```
bool equal(double x, double y)
{
    double eps = 1e-10;
    if (x > y + eps) return false;
    if (x < y - eps) return false;
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    double c = 0.1;
    for (double x = c; x < 5; x += c)
    {
        for (double y = c; y < 5; y += c)
        {
            if (equal(x + y, 5.0) && (x * x + y * y > 13))
            {
                std::cout << "x = " << x << "  y = " << y << std::endl;
                std::cout << x* x* x* x* x + y* y* y* y* y << std::endl;
            }
        }
    }
}
```