# Почему в массив c++ записывается некорректное значение?

Tags: c++, массивы

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n, j = 0;
    cout << "Amount of numbers: ";
    cin >> n;
    const int length = n;
    int numbers[length];

    if (length >= 1) {
        // Элементы с чётными индексами получают значение индекса, с нечётными - квадрата индекса
        while (j < length) {
            if (j % 2 == 0){
                numbers[j] = j;
            }
            else {
                numbers[j] = pow(j, 2);
            }
            j++;
        }
        // Выводим элементы массива
        j = 0;
        while (j < length) {
            cout << numbers[j] << endl;
            j++;
        }
    }

    system("pause>nul");
    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: По-хорошему, оно даже компилироваться не должно - нет в С++ массивов с длиной, определяемой во время выполнения...

Comment: @Harry так длина задаётся до выполнения, в строчке int numbers[length];

Comment: Да? И чему она равна? 5? 10? 22?

Comment: @Harry значению переменной n, вводимому пользователем с клавиатуры

Comment: Вы уж выбирайте что-то одно. "Длина задается до выполнения" или "длина вводится пользователем". Потому что вводится она во время выполнения... Кстати, если сделать нормально, то все работает - https://ideone.com/f3GZbS И, кстати, напишите нормально - `j*j`, а не эти извращения `pow(j,2)` - тоже *может* влиять, проверьте...

Comment: @Harry - посмотрев на код и приложенный скрин с результатами, я подумал, что перетрудился :). Однако еще остались места на земле, где возможны чудеса.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов чудес в программировании не бывает) как бы нам этого не хотелось...

Comment: @PavelNewSky - Вы полагаете, ИМХО, вот пример перед нами - некорректная инициализация массива - однако программа работает :)

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов но логика подсказывает, что раз компилятор сожрал такой код, значит ему нормально. корректность определяется тем, что хавает компилятор, а что нет. компилятор нами управляет :)

Comment: @PavelNewSky такое случалось во времена MS Dos, PC XT и QuicC, но на дворе 21 век. Поэтому я и говорю - чудеса :). Ладно нас сейчас отсюда погонят за флуд.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Сорян за тупой вопрос, я просто решаю задачи к 1 главе учебника по C++ и ещё не шарю. Я здесь создаю константу length и присваиваю ей значение, введённое пользователем. И массив имеет длину length, а length - константа, как и положено.

Comment: Все нормально. Вам в ответе написали про динамические массивы. Если бы будете работать с с++, то прямой смысл разобраться с этой темой. Это очень важно. Что касается pow(), то это эффекты округления до целых. Моя ирония направлена вовсе не на Вас.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов Ок, спасибо за разъяснения

Comment: Каким компилятором вы компилировали программу?

Comment: @wololo CodeBlocks

Comment: CodeBlocks - это среда, а не компилятор. Компилятор там gcc.  Возможность объявления массивов run-time размера является расширением компилятора gcc. К языку С++ это расширение отношения не имеет. В С++ это не разрешается.

Comment: @Homo Civicus, если Вы хотите, чтобы Вам помогали дальше, то поставьте зеленую галочку у ответа, который Вы считаете лучшим (по моему Ваша проблема решена) и проголосуйте "за" за остальные ответы, потому что люди на Вашу проблему тратили свое время.

Comment: @АлександрМуксимов сделано

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Типом возвращаемого значения [функции `std::pow()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/pow) является либо `float`, либо `double`, либо `long double`, т.е. возвращается значение с плавающей точкой.

В вашем примере, вы передаёте два аргумента типа `int`, и они оба внутри функции `pow` приводятся к типу `double`, и возвращаемое значение также имеет тип `double`.

Затем в вашем примере значение, возвращённое функцией `pow` и имеющее тип `double` приводится к типу `int`. В C++ типы с плавающей точкой приводятся к целочисленным типам путём [отбрасывания дробной части](http://eel.is/c++draft/conv.fpint#1) (так называемое округление в сторону нуля).

Так процесс возведения в степень осуществляется в числах с плавающей точкой, то нужно быть готовым к тому, что результат получится [не совсем точным](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82). Например, если точный результат некоторого вычисления равен `25`, то в общем случае результирующее значение может оказаться равным, например, `24.999999999999996`. Приведение этого значения к типу `int` отбросит дробную часть и в результате получится значение `24`.

Мне не удалось повторить вывод вашей программы, используя функцию `std::pow()` из заголовочного файла `<cmath>` (вероятно потому, что я использовал Visual Studio). Предполагаю, что, возможно, в вашем случае реализация функции `pow()` имеет примерно такой вид:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
double pow_bad(T1 base, T2 exp)
{
    return std::exp( double(exp) * std::log(double(base)) );
}
```

или что-либо подобное. Один из возможных результатов работы приведённой выше функции на ваших входных данных [будет таким](https://ideone.com/v3jprX):

```
i^2.0 = pow_bad(i, 2) int( pow_bad(i, 2) )
1^2.0 = 1 1
3^2.0 = 9.0000000000000018 9
5^2.0 = 24.999999999999996 24
7^2.0 = 48.999999999999993 48
9^2.0 = 81.000000000000028 81
11^2.0 = 121.00000000000003 121
13^2.0 = 169 169
```

Хотя вывод и не совпадает в точности с выводом вашей программы, но суть, думаю, понятна.

---

Попробуйте с помощью отладчика зайти внутрь функции `pow` и посмотреть как она устроена внутри. Возможно, что ничего интересного там не будет, но попробовать стоит.

Comment: Спасибо, понятно расписываете)

Answer (score 2):

Если вы хотите чтобы оно работало с размером массива который вводит пользователь, то нужно заменить

```
const int length = n;
int numbers[length];
```

на

```
int *numbers=  new int[n]
```

и перед

```
system("pause>nul");
```

добавить

```
delete[] numbers
```

почитайте про динамическую память в с++ https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_(C%2B%2B)

Comment: Это вообще никак не относится к вопросу.

Answer (score 2):

Функция pow не умножает значение x n раз, так как она также должна вычислять степень с использованием дробных показателей. Используйте другую функцию или напишите свою.
Функция pow (возможно, используя логарифмы) использует значения с плавающей запятой для вычисления значения степени, поэтому с int работает не так, как вам кажется, что она должна работать.
Также ваша функция для вычисления степени int будет явно работать быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Замените-ка для проверки

```
numbers[j] = pow(j, 2);
```

на

```
numbers[j] = j*j;
```

Потому что если не считать использованного нестандартного расширения, это единственное слабое место...

P.S. Не понимаю две любви студентов - к `float` вместо `double` и к `pow` там, где она совсем ни к чему...

Comment: Да, при таком варианте выводятся корректные значения. Видимо, функция pow() работает не так, как я предполагал.