# Почему pow работает неверно в компиляторе MinGW

Tags: c++, mingw

Есть примитивный код

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n = 5;
    int cnt = 2;
    int q = pow(n,cnt);
    cout << q;
    return  0;
}
```

И почему то при компиляции под MinGW выводит 24, почему это так?

Comment: Потому что `pow` дает `double`, кторый может оказаться, например, 24.999999999999999, и при преобразовании в int дробная часть отбрасывается. В стандарте не сказано, **как именно** `pow` должна выполнять вычисления...

Comment: в VS используется `pow<int,int>` и всё считается ок, без обвеса

Comment: Похожий вопрос: [Почему в массив c++ записывается некорректное значение?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782217).

Comment: @PavelGridin Если покопаться, то `pow<int,int>` перегоняет аргументы в `double`.

Comment: Что значит под `MinGW`? Там разные компиляторы бывают. Вот `gcc` последний, выводит 25. https://godbolt.org/z/k5-yEc

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Ошибка при возведении в степень](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/137699/%d0%9e%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b8-%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c)

Comment: задайте flout или double вместо int

Answer (score 0):

Потому что `pow` возвращает результат типа `double`, который может, из-за [ошибок вещественных чисел](https://habr.com/ru/post/309812/) оказаться, например, 24.999999999999999. Далее, т.к. тип "принимающей" переменной – `int`, возвращённый `double` будет тоже преобразован в `int`, а при преобразовании к `int` дробная часть отбрасывается, в результате чего и получается 24.

В стандарте не сказано, как именно `pow` должна выполнять вычисления...