# определить, какая цифра стоит в разряде с номером i

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    long long int numb;
    int count;
    cout << "enter number: ";
    cin >> numb;
    int n = 0;
    for (; numb > 0; n++) {
        numb /= 10;
    }
    
    cout << n << endl;

    int i, digit=0;
    cout << "enter i: ";
    cin >> i;
    digit=  (numb / pow(10, i)) % 10;
    cout << "digit = " << digit;
    return 0;

}
```

нужно определить, какая цифра стоит в разряде с номером i (разряды
нумеруются с конца, т.е. разряд единиц имеет номер 0). в моём случае digit всегда равняется нулю. Как это исправить?

Comment: И что, вот это — `digit=  (numb / pow(10, i)) % 10;` — скомпилировалось?... 8-/

Comment: Так Вы ж сами сначала в цикле уменьшаете `numb` до нуля

Comment: я добавил еще одну переменную для numb и  digit=(int)(numb/pow(10,i))%10, и всё заработало) спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ```
> digit=  (numb / pow(10, i)) % 10;
> ```

```
digit = (numb / (long long)pow(10, i)) % 10;
```

Предупреждение: оказывается, некоторые компиляторы используют функцию `pow`, вычисляющую подобное возведение в степень неточно, даже несмотря на то, что все точные значения представимы в типе `double`. Поэтому вместо использования функции `pow` стоит либо сделать свою функцию, работающую с целыми числами, либо сохранить степени 10 в массив.

А ещё лучше просто делить число на 10 заданное количество раз.

Comment: `(long)pow(10, i)` А если `pow(10, 2)` вернёт, например, `99.99...`, то отработает ли программа корректно?

Comment: @wololo, double имеет 53 значащих бита и все числа до 2\*\*53 представляет точно; long long имеет 64 бита, что больше, однако, 10\*\*x = 5\*\*x \* 2\*\*x, так что для точного значения достаточно, чтобы 5\*\*x влезло в 53 бита. long может содержать числа до 20 знаков, а log2(5\*\*2) < 47, так что все степени 10, которые помещаются в long, точно представимы и в double. Погрешности вычисления в этом коде не возникнет.

Comment: @wololo, ну и если хочется убедиться, то `for (var x=1n; x<(1n<<64n); x*=10n) if (x !== BigInt(Number(x))) console.log(x); x-=10n; if (x !== BigInt(Number(x))) console.log("DONE");` выводит только `DONE`.

Comment: @wololo, ну или вот так: `for (var q=0; 10n**BigInt(q) == 10**q; ++q); console.log(q)` - получится 23.

Comment: `double имеет 53 значащих бита и все числа до 2**53 представляет точно` Это не важно, т.к. ни стандарт IEEE-754, ни стандарт языка C не требуют, чтобы функция `pow` возвращала точный математический результат, если он (точный математический результат возведения в степень) представим типом `double`.

Comment: `var q=0; ... 10**q` ECMA-262 также не требует, чтобы операция возведения в степень над Number возвращала точный результат. См. описание абстрактной операции `Number::exponentiate`, через которую определяется семантика оператора `**` и `Math.pow()`: [`ECMA-262/6.1.6.1.3/13`](https://262.ecma-international.org/12.0/#sec-numeric-types-number-exponentiate): `Return an implementation-approximated value representing the result of raising ℝ(base) to the ℝ(exponent) power.`.

Comment: Если разработчики JS-движка, либо авторы Сишной версии функции, которую может в своих недрах вызывать движок, подошли основательно к реализации операции возведения в степень, то конечно можно получить корректный результат, но никаких гарантий нет, и если хочется убедиться, то: [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/137699), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/782217), [3](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1141015).

Comment: @wololo, да, неожиданно... Получается, в рандомных версиях некоторых компиляторах pow почему-то работает не так, как в других версиях, и не так, как в js? Я думал, что с одним и тем же типом везде должно работать одинаково...

Comment: @wololo, добавил предупреждение в ответ.