# Странность округления double (c#, .net-core)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, .net-core, .netcore2.0

Вот тест (xUnit), который у меня выполняется успешно, и это плохо для меня:

```
        double value1 = 2097151.135;
        double value2 = 2097152.135;
        double expected1 = 2097151.14;
        double expected2 = 2097152.13;
        double result1 = Math.Round( value1, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero );
        double result2 = Math.Round( value2, 2, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero );
        Assert.Equal( expected1, result1, 2 );
        Assert.Equal( expected2, result2, 2 );
```

У меня вопрос, почему именно для чисел, начиная с 2_097_152 начинает неверно работать округление, не так, как описано в документации на метод Round()

У меня Visual Studio 2017 + c# + .net core 2.0

Answer (score 6):

Дело в том, что десятичные числа с дробной частью не представимы точно в формате double.

2097151.135 это примерно 2.09715113500000000931322574615*10<sup>6</sup>

2097152.135 это примерно 2.09715213499999977648258209229*10<sup>6</sup>

Поэтому одно округляется в к 2.09715114*10<sup>6</sup>, а второе - к 2.09715113*10<sup>6</sup> (точнее к их ближайшим представимым в double значениям).

Если вам нужно точное представление для десятичный чисел - используйте decimal.

Если хотите подробностей - почитайте вопрос-ответ [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/).