# создать 2 int числа из одного float

Tags: c++, c

Необходимо создать 2 числа из одного с плавающей точкой. float 15.635 = int 15 | int 635. Проблема состоит  в том, что необходимо найти точку,но ведь для этого необходимо создать из него строку и парсить по ней, но тип float нельзя перевести в  строку, а даже если сделать это, то как разделить(желательно сразу с вариантом приравнивания)

Comment: *"тип float нельзя перевести в строку"* Не понял. Можно ведь использовать `printf` или `std::to_string`. Или речь о том, что нельзя сделать это простым кастом?

Comment: Еще, хорошо бы выбрать 1 язык. С или С++? Или вам подходят решения на обоих?

Comment: лучше конечно на c++

Comment: `.1+.2` - что ожидается?

Comment: Вот вам [`0.3f`, напечатанное с полной точностью](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d8b01c1280b83d40).

Comment: как это связано с физическим разделением числа по точке на 2 числа?

Comment: Зачем что-то парсить? Округлить float, вот Вам и целая часть. Потом вычесть из float целую часть, вот Вам и дробная часть. Ну да, и округлять надо в меньшую сторону. Поможет floor() или даже trunc().

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев Многие числа не могут быть представлены во `float` точно. Например, `0.25` может быть представлено точно, а `0.3` - не может, ведь если перевести `0.3` в двоичный вид, вы получите бесконечное количество знаков после точки (`0.01(0011)...`). Поэтому когда вы пытаетесь присвоить `0.3` `float`у, число немного меняется - заменяется на ближайшее представимое. Как показывает ссылка, это `0.300000011920928955078125`. Как вы собираетесь определять, сколько символов после точки брать из такого числа?

Comment: Вообще, в каком виде вы получаете число? В виде `float` или в виде строки?

Comment: float. количество знаков после запятой не будет более 5

Comment: Актуально еще ?

Comment: есть такая чудная функция - https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/modf - правда нужно будет подумать, что с дробной частью делать

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
float f = 15.635;
int i_part = f;
int f_part = (f - i_part) * 1000 + 0.5;

printf("%d.%03d", i_part, f_part);
```

Само собой, подразумевается, что целая часть умещается в тип `int`.

**Updated**

> как узнать количество знаков дробной части?

Как уже [объясняли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82/417454#417454), числа с плавающей точкой 
надёжно не представляют десятичные дроби, так что достоверно узнать количество знаков после десятичного разделителя можно только округлив число до какой-либо адекватной величины, а затем избавившись от лишнего, например как-то так:

```
int i_part = f;
const int max_f_digits = 5;
int f_part = (f - i_part) * pow(10, max_f_digits) + 0.5;
int f_digits=max_f_digits;

if (f_part) {
  while (f_part%10 == 0) {
    f_part/=10;
    f_digits--;
  }
} else {
  f_digits=1;
}

printf("%d.%0*d\n", i_part, f_digits, f_part);
```

Comment: банально,но как узнать количество знаков дробной части?

Comment: @ДенисЛебедев, добавил; ЗЫ: на будущее: добавляй в вопрос больше одного примера, дабы предупредить разночтения...

Answer (score 7):

Я тут подумал на досуге. Задание какое-то странное. К примеру, рассмотрим три числа:

15.1
15.01
15.001

Согласно заданию, дробная часть каждого из этих чисел должна быть представлена в виде:

1
01
001

Но число 001 выгруженное в int равно числу 1, так как лидирующие нули отбрасываются как незначащие. Получается, что дробные части у чисел 15.1, 15.01, 15.001 выгруженные в целое по предложенному алгоритму будут равны между собой и равны единице. А это, очевидно, не тот результат, который ожидается.

Вы уточните, что именно Вам нужно. Потому, что выгрузка дробной части в целое не может быть однозначной из-за наличия лидирующих нулей в дробной части.

От этой неоднозначности можно избавится, если, как Вы пишите, ограничить число знаков в дробной части не более 5. Тогда можно выгружать дробную часть в целое исходя из этого. Но при этом 15.635 будет равно 15.63500 и дробная часть будет 63500, а не 635. Соответственно в вышеприведенных примерах числа будут такие:

15.10000
15.01000
15.00100

И их дробные части, выгруженные в целое, будут такие:

10000=10000
01000=1000
00100=100

Или Вы действительно получаете строку, а не число. Тогда, конечно, можно распарсить строку и выделить строку целого и строку дробной части. Но это просто задача разбора строки, а не задача разбора числа float. И на выходе Вы получите не целые числа, а опять же строки.

UPD1:

И да, еще же есть отрицательные числа. Или в этом случае рассматриваются только положительные числа?