# Почему в for'е именно sqrt(n) + 0.00001?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main()
{
    int n;
    system("chcp 1251");
    printf("Введите целое число\t");
    scanf_s("%d", &n);

    for (int i = 2; i < sqrt(n) + 0.00001; ) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            printf("%d ", i);
            n /= i;
        }
        else {
            ++i;
        }
    }

    if (n > 1)
        printf("%d", n);
    getchar(); getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Вот простой код на С, который выводит простые делители числа.

Пример: 2600 = 2*2*2*5*5*13. Так вот, почему в for'е написано именно sqrt(n) + 0.00001?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`i < sqrt(n) + 0.00001` — это аналог `i <= sqrt(n)` с учётом неточностей при вычислений дробных чисел. Автор алгоритма решил (или просто взял с потолка), что эта неточность — промах счётчика мимо значения корня — будет не более одной стотысячной, оттуда и константа.

Если переводить на человеческий язык, условие буквально означает «останови цикл, когда значение `i` *чуть-чуть* превысит значение квадратного корня из `n`».

Comment: Но почему просто не i <= n?

Comment: кстати, любопытно, что на большинстве платформ (с 32-битным `int` и IEEE754 `double`)  этот пример будет работать корректно даже при сравнении с `<=` т.к. целые типы представляются без погрешности... само собой, я не рекомендую и не оправдываю использование таких тонких и зыбких механик где-либо...

Comment: @Asmund, связанный вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82/417454#417454... и в данном случае правильно было бы избавиться от арифметики с плавающей точкой и использовать `i*i <= n`.

Comment: @Asmund Ошибка может накопиться как в меньшую сторону, так и в большую. `i <= n` не учтёт второй случай, из-за чего, к примеру, значение `4.0000015268` будет ошибочно пропущено при `n = 16`.

Comment: @Asmund ... или наоборот, квадратный корень выдаст значение меньше идеального, из-за чего последнее значение `i` опять же будет пропущено. Это целочисленная арифметика гарантирует неявное округление после каждой операции, которое сбрасывает неточности. При `double` же и `float` нам приходится самим учитывать наличие погрешности и её рост.

Comment: Если вопрос не конкретно про sqrt() + EPS, то никогда так не работайте с нецелочисленным типом данных. А с учетом тяжести операции sqrt() - это ужас. Вариант с целыми числами: i * i <= n.

Comment: @Arhad "не более одной десятимиллионной" - стотысячной, если позанудствовать...

Comment: @tum_, спасибо, исправил.