# Почему значение кнопки после нажатия -399.999 вместо -400 по координатам "y"?

Tags: c#, unity3d-android, unity3d-ui

Вообщем,проблема в том что после нажатия кнопки, координаты по "y" вместо -400 - -399.999,как решить?

код передвижения персонажа :

```
  if (PosBtnLeft != btnLeft.transform.position.y)
        {
            Debug.Log("True");
        }
        else if (PosBtnRight != btnRight.transform.position.y)
        {

            Debug.Log("True");
        }
        else
        {
            run = 0f;
            Debug.Log("False");
        }

        rb.velocity = new Vector2(run, rb.velocity.y);
```

код анимации кнопок :

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class buttons : MonoBehaviour,IPointerDownHandler,IPointerUpHandler
{

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x,transform.position.y+ 0.2f);

    }
    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(transform.position.x, transform.position.y - 0.2f);
    }
}
```

Comment: ну это может быть просто потому что double или что вы юзаете - не гарантирует 100% точности

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178988

Answer (score 2):

типы данных float, они не могут расчитываться точно, можешь это проверить: прибавляю по нажатии кнопки постоянно 0.01 и смотри за значением будет что-то типа того(0, 0.01, 0.019999, 0.0300012) это не исправить, да и исправлять не нужно, этого даже глаз не заметит в чем проблема?)  4 = 3.999...