# Путь между двумя точками

Tags: алгоритм, golang, вычислительная-геометрия

Разбираюсь с перемещением персонажа на стороне сервера.
Клиент присылает точку куда выполняется движение персонажа и мне требуется получить координаты каждого тика на протяжении всего пути.

Но получается так , что конечная точка к которой я движусь не совпадает c точкой которую я получаю при помощи прибавления смещения

```
CurPosX := float64(294397)
CurPosY := float64(197421)
NewPosX := float64(294277)
NewPosY := float64(197670)

dx := NewPosX - CurPosX
dy := NewPosY - CurPosY

distance := math.Sqrt(dx*dx+dy*dy)

offsetX := dx / distance
OffsetY := dy / distance

bx := CurPosX
bz := CurPosZ

for i := 0; i < int(distance)+3; i++ {
    bx += offsetX
    bz += OffsetZ
    fmt.Printf("%f X %f\n", bx, by)
}
```

Подскажите, пожалуйста, где я туплю.

UPD: Хочу уточнить, иногда я все же попадаю в нужную точку. Вероятно это как-то связано с направлением движения

Comment: а почему `int(distance)+3`?

Comment: Вам нужна линейная интерполяция, это функция от времени.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178988

Comment: Я бы сделал это так: задал бы `n` - количество дискретных точек, которое нужно получить, найти модуль `Dx = |x1-x2|` и `Dy = |y1 - y2|`. Затем найти `dx = Dx / n` и `dy = Dy / n`. Ну и в цикле от 1 до n делал `curX += dx` и `curY += dy`.

Comment: Хочу уточнить, иногда я все же попадаю в нужную точку. Вероятно это как-то связано с направлением движения

Comment: Вы относительно правильно делаете... Вероятнее всего у вас ошибки округления, и в отдельных случаях результат после округления правильный. Если вы двигаетесь вдоль осей координат - то там округления как правило не будет.

Comment: @AndreiKhotko, с `+=` всё равно фигня получится.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По идее должно помочь:

```
CurPosX := float64(294397)
CurPosY := float64(197421)
NewPosX := float64(294277)
NewPosY := float64(197670)

dx := NewPosX - CurPosX
dy := NewPosY - CurPosY

distance := math.Sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy)
n = int(distance)

for i := 0; i <= n; i++ {
    bx := CurPosX + dx * i / n
    by := CurPosY + dy * i / n
    fmt.Printf("%f X %f\n", bx, by)
}
```

[Подробнее о вычислениях с плавающей точкой.](//ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178988)

Comment: Благодарю! Это помогло)