# Postgresql double или numeric?

Tags: sql, postgresql

numeric - Данный тип следует выбирать для хранения денежных сумм, а также в других случаях, когда требуется гарантировать точность вычислений.
Ни раз встречал программистов которые вместо numeric в PostgreSQL использовали double. Так же и в MySQL знакомый всегда использует double для тех же денег. Слышал что есть обсуждения насчет не точности double, но как вижу все его используют и не парятся. Хотелось бы спросить зачем нам нужен numeric тогда если есть real или double?
Хотелось бы узнать зачем неточные типы когда есть точные?

Comment: *Хотелось бы спросить зачем нам нужен numeric тогда если есть real или double?* Вообще более естественным был бы обратный вопрос - нахрена неточные типы, когда есть точные. Но, судя по всему, Вы имеете ответ на этот вопрос...

Comment: @Akina я новичок поэтому и спрашиваю, хотелось бы узнать зачем неточные типы когда есть точные?

Comment: *зачем неточные типы когда есть точные?* А с ними математика быстрее.

Comment: @Akina то есть с точными типами операции работают быстрее и существенно возрастает скорость?

Comment: Наоборот. Точные типы медленнее. Но точнее.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
melkij=> create temp table doublecalc (v double precision);
CREATE TABLE
melkij=> insert into doublecalc values (0.1), (0.2);
INSERT 0 2
melkij=> select sum(v) = 0.3 from doublecalc ;
 ?column? 
----------
 f
```

Что? Почему условие не выполняется? Потому что числа с плавающей запятой [работают именно так](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/203622) (возможно вопрос необходимо вовсе закрыть как дубликат).

Справедливо и для postgresql и для mysql и для многих других. Вообще если вы назовёте float или double что-то не относящееся к IEEE 754 - вас не поймут. А всё основанное на IEEE 754 по своему определению является приближёнными вычислениями. И потому не может применяться в областях, где нужны точные вычисления. Ну и, разумеется, применяются и там тоже, а потом мучительно ищут ошибки. Людям свойственно делать глупости, но это не значит что эти глупости надо повторять.

Поэтому если вы хотите хранить деньги в числах с плавающей запятой - то вы или обосновываете что именно так необходимо сделать именно здесь или получаете больно по рукам при прохождении code review в любом приличном проекте.

Comment: Тогда получается, что я для денег использую в Postgresql  тип numeric т.к мне нужны точные цифры, а где тогда допустим я могу использовать double?

Comment: Там где вам нужны числа с плавающей запятой и при том точности float недостаточно. Поищите в науках, например, где нужны быстрые вычисления и всё равно на +- метр потому что сравниваем километры.