# Как сложить два многочлена разной длины

Tags: c#

В общем, есть функция с перегруженным оператором сложения. Если степень многочленов одинаковая, то всё считает спокойно, но если степень многочленов разная, то одночлены складываются неправильно(т.е одночлен второй степени может прибавиться к одночлену третьей степени и т.д.) Вроде бы должно быть простое решение, но я его не нахожу.

```
 public static Polynomial operator +(Polynomial One, Polynomial Two)
        {
            int pow1 = One.power;
            int pow2 = Two.power;
            double[] coeff1 = new double[pow1 + 1];
            Polynomial Three = new Polynomial(coeff1, pow1);
            for (int i = 0; i < One.power + 1; i++)
            {
                Three.coeff[i] = One.coeff[i] + Two.coeff[i];
            }
            return Three;
            }
        public void Output(Polynomial One)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i <= power; i++)
            {
                Console.Write(One.coeff[i] + "x" + "^" + (power-i));
                if (i < power)
                {
                    Console.Write("+");
                }

            }
            Console.WriteLine(" ");
        }
```

Comment: Нормализовать их сначала надо к единой степени, добавлением нулей в соотв. степени. А по завершении - удалять нули. Ибо после сложения степень-то может и понизиться...

Comment: как у вас хранятся компоненты многочлена? Есть разные варианты решения, с нормализацией и без, зависит от того как храните компоненты

Comment: @rdorn, коэффициенты записываются в массив, степени записываются в обычную переменную

Comment: Каким образом вы отличаете `x^2+1` от `x^2+x+1`? Добавьте в вопрос ту часть класса, которая отвечает за хранение и наполнение многочлена.

Comment: @rdorn, добавлено, если я вас правильно поняла.

Comment: не совсем то что надо, но я понял и ошибки увидел. Вы работаете с коэффициентами в обратном порядке. Подробности и некоторые улучшения в ответе, остальное сделаете по аналогии, главное разберитесь что там зачем и почему

Comment: @rdorn, пробую разбираться. Если вам нетрудно, вы говорите, что есть более удобные способы, намекните хотя бы в какой стороне эти удобные способы. Для общего развития.

Comment: А это смотря что хотите получить. Этот быстрый, но избыточен по хранимым данным и несколько не очевиден, хотя это субъективно. Можно сделать на базе Dictionary<степень, коэфф.> - будет компактнее по хранению и очевиднее, но сложнее в некоторых моментах. Можно описать класс для одночленов и собирать многочлен тупо списком - тоже что-то будет проще, что-то сложнее. Смотря для каких целей. Для учебного задания этот вариант всем хорош, главное понять как его правильно использовать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

И так, как я понял (поправьте если ошибся), структуру вашего полинома можно представить следующим образом:

```
class Polinomial
{
  //точность вычислений для операций с плавающей точкой
  private static readonly double _precision = 0.0001;

  //массив под коэффициенты, по-умолчанию, инициализируем пустым
  private readonly double[] _coeff = new double[0];

  //добавим индексатор для доступа к коэффициентам на чтение
  //подобные объекты лучше делать неизменяемыми
  public double this[int index] => _coeff[index];

  //степень хранить не требуется, длина массива хранится, а не вычисляется
  public int Power => _coeff.Length - 1;

  //конструктор принимающий массив у вас уже есть, параметр степень там избыточен,
  //что будет если передать степень большую чем длина массива? убираем степень из параметров
  public Polinomial(double[] coeff)
  {
    _coeff = coeff;
  }

  public static Polinomial operator +(Polinomial a, Polinomial b)
  {
    //выбираем полином наибольшей и наименьшей степени
    Polinomial maxPowerPoly = a.Power < b.Power ? b : a;
    Polinomial minPowerPoly = a.Power < b.Power ? a : b;

    //создаем массив для предварительного результата
    double[] predResult = new double[maxPowerPoly.Power + 1];

    //складываем члены начиная с нулевой до максимальной степени для полинома меньшей степени
    for(int i = 0; i < minPowerPoly.Power + 1; i++)
    {
      predResult[i] = minPowerPoly[i] + maxPowerPoly[i];
    }

    //дописываем старшие члены от полинома большей степени
    for(int i = minPowerPoly.Power + 1; i < maxPowerPoly.Power + 1; i++)
    {
      predResult[i] = maxPowerPoly[i];
    }

    //ищем индекс наибольшего не нулевого элемента массива
    //при сложении полиномов одинаковой степени, степень может и уменьшиться
    int notZeroIndex = predResult.Length - 1;

    //все  что меньше заданной точности по модулю - считаем нулем
    while(Math.Abs(predResult[notZeroIndex]) < _precision)
    {
      notZeroIndex--;
    }

    //формируем окончательный результат
    double[] result = new double[notZeroIndex+1];
    for(int i = 0; i < result.Length; i++)
    {
      //если значение меньше заданной точности - заменяем его на явный ноль
      result[i] = Math.Abs(predResult[i]) < _precision ? 0.0 : predResult[i];
    }
    return new Polinomial(result);
  }

  //ну и, в качестве бонуса, сделаем нормальный вывод через ToString
  //чтобы можно было просто сунуть переменную нашего типа в Console.WriteLine
  public override string ToString()
  {
    StringBuilder res = new StringBuilder();
    if(Power == 1)
    {
      res.Append(_coeff[Power].ToString("0.####x"));
    }
    else
    {
      res.Append(_coeff[Power].ToString("0.####x^"));
      res.Append(Power);
    }
    for (int i = Power - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
      if(Math.Abs(_coeff[i]) > _precision)
      {
        if(i > 1)
        {   
          res.Append(_coeff[i].ToString("+0.####x^;-0.####x^"));
          res.Append(Power);
        }
        else if(i > 0)
        {
          res.Append(_coeff[i].ToString("+0.####x;-0.####x"));
        }
        else
        {
          res.Append(_coeff[i].ToString("+0.####;-0.####"));
        }
      }
    }
    return res.ToString();
  }

  //остальное допишете сами по аналогии
}
```

По поводу того, зачем нужна "точность" и почему вы, почти никогда, не получите честный ноль при вычитании, можете почитать в соседнем [вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/198316)

Важное уточнение: все это будет работать при одном, но важном условии - индекс коэффициента в массиве должен совпадать со степенью элемента полинома, к которому относится данный коэффициент. Это значит, что полином вида
`x^2 + 2x + 3`
будет представлен массивом
`new double[]{ 3.0, 2.0, 1.0 }`
иными словами запись коэффициентов будет в обратном порядке, относительно принятого в математике, ну и пустые элементы промежуточных степеней также придется хранить постоянно. В вашем коде данное условие было нарушено, коэффициенты хранились в прямом порядке, из-за чего и возникала проблема при сложении.

Эти условия накладывает выбранный вами способ хранения коэффициентов.