# Проверка числа на целость

Tags: python, математика

Нужно, чтобы программа проверяла является ли число точным кубом. Я написал так:

```
import math

n=int(input())
if (pow(n,1/3)).is_integer():
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Но когда ввожу число 8 - все верно пишет "yes". Но если ввести 125, 216 и другие точные кубы, то почему-то выдает -"no". В чем ошибка?

Пробовал вместо pow(n,1/3) использовать n**(1/3) - та же проблема.

Comment: Попробуй n задать не целым, а float

Comment: Ошибка в попытке использовать плавающую арифметику в целочисленной по сути задаче.

Comment: А как правильно?

Comment: Почему у вас в заголовке про целость, а в вопросе про куб?

Comment: кстати, во втором питоне выражение `pow(n,1/3))` всегда равно единице

Answer (score 3, accepted):

python, как и большинство других языков, не отличит число `1/3` от числа достаточно близкого к нему

```
>>> 1/3 == 0.33333333333333331234512345
True
```

Точность вычислений с плавающей точкой ограничена, поэтому все сравнения дробных чисел нужно производить с учетом погрешности, например так.

```
if round(pow(n, 1/3), 6).is_integer(): # сравнение с точностью до 0.000001
```

Правда, стоит сказать, что от всех проблем это не убережет: если числа достаточно большие, потеря точности проявится значительно сильнее.

```
>>> round((123123123**3) ** (1/3), 6)
123123123.0
>>> round((1231231231**3) ** (1/3), 6)
1231231230.999999
```

```
>>> 100000000000000000.0 == 99999999999999999.0
True
```

### Upd:

Целочисленный алгоритм нахождения кубического корня (с отбрасыванием дробной части)

```py
def intcuberoot(n):
    if n < 0:
        return -intcuberoot(-n)
    elif n < 2:
        return n
    else:
        x = intcuberoot(n >> 3) << 1
        return x if (x + 1) ** 3 > n else x + 1

def iscube(n):
    return intcuberoot(n) ** 3 == n
```

У него тоже есть свои ограничения - он не особо оптимальный да и упрется в потолок рекурсии на огромных числах, но явная ошибка лучше чем неточный результат.

```py
>>> iscube(555**300)
True
```

### Upd2

Итеративный алгоритм (без ограничений на размер числа)

```
def intcuberoot2(n):
    if n < 0:
        return -intcuberoot2(-n)

    x = 0

    for bit in range((n.bit_length() + 2) // 3, -1, -1):
        if (x | 1 << bit) ** 3 <= n:
            x |= 1 << bit

    return x
```

Comment: добавлю, что условие `round(n**1./3),2)**3 == n` будет давать правильный результат для всего диапазона... ЗЫ: [связаный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82)

Comment: @Fat-Zer смотря что называть диапазоном :) 2**150 входит в диапазон чисел двойной точности (даже записывается без потерь).

Comment: да... что-то я очитался — мне казалось, что ограничение для `n` до 10⁹

Comment: Значит лучший вариант - это просто  перебирать числа меньшие заданного числа? Если куб совпадет - ответ да..

Comment: @starter Мой ответ был больше не о том, как правильно, а о том, почему не сработал ваш вариант. Перебирать полностью конечно не нужно, но чтобы гарантированно получить верный результат, лучше не переходить на вычисления с плавающей точкой (обновил ответ). Fat-Zer и Harry предложили хороший компромисс между точностью и простотой вычислений.

Answer (score 3):

Я бы действовал так - округлял кубический корень до ближайшего целого, и проверял, совпадает ли его куб с исходным числом.

Если не ошибаюсь, на Python'е это выглядит так:

```
n = int(input())
c = round(pow(n,1/3))

if c*c*c == n:
    print("yes")
else:
    print("no")
```

Понятно, что при больших значениях начнет играть роль погрешность вычисления кубического корня...