# Как точно вычислить корень n степени числа

Tags: python, python-3.x

Например необходимо вычислить корень 3 степени из 27000. Я записывал следующими способами

```
a = pow(27000, 1/3) # ответ выходит примерно 29.99999993
a = 27000**(1/3) # ответ тот же
```

Пытался использовать модуль fractions , но ответ не меняется. Как найти точное число, если есть такая возможность. Округление не желательно

Comment: Использовать математические ряды?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Кубический корень из числа](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/946481/%d0%9a%d1%83%d0%b1%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0)

Comment: Похожий [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1021897/%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%86%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C). Там я предложил алгоритм целочисленного вычисления кубического корня. его можно обобщить для корня n-ной степени.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Это общая проблема почти любого языка программирования. Дело в том, что континуум значений множества реальных значений каким-то способом надо отобразить на конечный набор машинных значений. Обычно это делается методом, который описывается стандартом [IEEE 754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754)

64 битовая (двойная точность) раскладка битов будет такая

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Соответственно принципиально есть числа, которые непредставимы точно - в данном случае 1/3 - не представимо точно. Возникнет невязка в районе `1e-8`, что и дает `29.99999999`

Можно посмотреть на точность представления [например здесь](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Answer (score 6):

Можно использовать модуль [SymPy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/tutorial/index.html):

```
from sympy import simplify   #  pip install sympy
```

---

```
In [124]: simplify("27000 ** (1/3)")
Out[124]: 30
```