# Как корректно проверить точность до десятых или сотых?

Tags: c#, asp.net, математика, числа-с-плавающей-точкой

Есть веб-форма, на которой 2 текст бокса, в эти текстбоксы заносятся значения, `double`, их я проверяю, чтобы они были с точностью до двух знаков после запятой.

Делаю я это следующим образом:

```
if ((Thickness1 * 100) % 1 != 0 || (Thickness2 * 100) % 1 != 0)
{
      Master.AlertMessage = "Толщина стенки до и после зачистки должна быть указана с точностью до десятых или до сотых";
      return false;
}
```

Но он все равно не пропускает числа, которые с двумя знаками после запятой или с одним

Значения которые попадают : `Thickness1 = 8.95` и `Thickness2 = 7.45`

Может подсказать кто, в чем моя ошибка?

UPD:

Преобразование числа которое приходит из текстбокса в `Double`

```
 Double Thickness1 = 0;
 Double Thickness2 = 0;
 Double.TryParse(txbZachistkaThickness1.Text.Replace('.', ',').Trim(), out Thickness1);
 Double.TryParse(txbZachistkaThickness2.Text.Replace('.', ',').Trim(), out Thickness2);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Берите строки, и смотрите, что там после точки.

В конце концов, 1.00 - это тоже величина с точностью до сотых :)

И еще - подумайте - какой, кроме нулевого, может быть остаток при делении на 1? (увы, не знаю, как в C#, но в С/С++ `%` - операция целочисленная, и `%1` всегда равен 0...)

Comment: число 8,96 допустим при умножении на сто выдавало не 896, а 896,00000000011, как так получается? брал например 8,84 и такой пробелмы не было, в чем косяк? как тогда правильно умножить?

Comment: получается, что я не правильно храню числа?

Comment: @Sosiska, а вы уверены что толщина стенки ровно 8,96, а не 8,9600000000011 ? Скорее всего нет, вы не можете быть в этом уверены. А значит вам это на самом деле не важно. Для желаемого вами поведения валидируйте  введённые строки до конвертации в численный тип. Или используйте компонент заточенный на ввод десятичных чисел.

Comment: @4per ну я же смотрю глазками в дебаггер, он мне и пишет, что в переменную сохраняется именно 8,96, а не 8,9600000000011

Comment: Мы въезжаем в новую тему - представление в компьютере чисел с плавающей точкой. Грубо - то, что после точки, хранится как сумма дробей вида 1/2^n. И никак **точно** вы не представите, например, 0.2. Поэтому и говорю вам - смотрите числа **до** преобразования во внутренний формат...

Comment: и ДО преобразования число тоже самое, но только в случае, когда я умножаю на сто, он это число мне выдаёт не целым

Comment: т.е. числа 8.96 или 9.96 или 8.95 или 9.95 при умножении на сто не выдаст мне целое число, а число 9.99 с этим проблем не испытывает

Comment: @Sosiska, потому что https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/218063 Используйте decimal