# Некорректное вычитание double. В чем проблема, как исправить?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, double

```
            double dTest1 = Convert.ToDouble("1005,502247");
            double dTest2 = Convert.ToDouble("1005,142247");
            double dTest3 ;
            dTest3 = (dTest1 - dTest2);
```

На выходе в отладчике dTest3  0.36000000000001364. Откуда хвост, что это, как исправлять?

Comment: неточность хранения такого типа данных. используйте decimal

Comment: Это, в общем, очевидно!  Просто так ведь не должно быть!? Это явно проблема Microsoft?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: Честно, подозревал что есть дубликат!!!! Искал!!! Не смог найти! Это постоянно повторяется!!! Искал с тегами. решение этой проблемы синонимизация тегов!!!?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Это проблема проявляется не только с C#, но и в C++, js, python, java etc - везде, где есть тип числа с плавающей точкой, и связана с тем, как число с плавающей точкой вычисляется и хранится в памяти компьютера. И касается она не только double, но и float.

Если вдаться в подробности, то число с плавающей точкой типа double(float) хранится в памяти в виде мантисы и экспоненты в двоичном виде. При чем длина мантисы ограничена 23 битами для float, и 52 - для double, а экспоненты - 8-ю и 11-ю соответственно. В этом случае значение переменной вычисляется по формуле:
 `(-1)^sign* (1.m) * (2 ^ e)`. Такой подход обеспечивает точность не более 7-ми знаков после запятой для float и 15 - для double.

Как происходит запись?

Возьмём пример числа:

```
double d = 12;
```

`12 = (8+4)=(1+1/2)*2^3`. - здесь экспонента будет равна 100 (3 в бинарном виде), а мантисса - 1 (поскольку 1/2 - в бинарном виде 0.1).. - это простой пример, и он вполне может храниться в памяти без потери. От простого к сложному:

```
2.1 = (2 + 0.1)=(1+0.05)*2
```

Тут уже `e=1`
А вот m=?

Здесь ждёт сюрприз:

Можете проверить меня, переведя 0.05 из десятичной в двоичную систему. На моём калькуляторе результат выглядит так:

m = 00001100110011001100110011001100110011001100110011

Очевидно, что при хранении этого числа будет потеряна точность.

Что можно почитать на тему:

- [Обсуждение операций](https://m.habr.com/ru/post/331814/) над double на хабр
- Там же о том, как [хранится](https://m.habr.com/ru/company/xakep/blog/257897/) в памяти переменная с плавающей точкой
- Офф. Доки [Microsoft](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/cpp/c-language/type-float?view=vs-2019)
- Просто [неплохая статья](https://neerc.ifmo.ru/wiki/index.php?title=%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BB_%D1%81_%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9)

**Решение:**

Для решения сложившейся ситуации есть несколько путей:

1. Решение в лоб: округлить результат выполнения операций над double/float с помощью [Math.Round](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.math.round?view=netcore-3.0):

   var r = Math.Round(d, 2);
2. Использовать специальный тип для хранения чисел с плавающей точкой под названием [Decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.decimal?view=netcore-2.2). Это надёжное и впрочем рекомендуемое решение, но нужно учесть, что при больших вычислениях может быть незначитедьная потеря в производительности

Comment: Ответ лучше, чем в дубликате.