# Почему сравнение одинаковых чисел выдает false?

Tags: c#, unity3d

У меня есть этот код:

```
bool areEqual = tiles[i].transform.position.z == transform.position.z;
Debug.Log($"{tiles[i].transform.position.z} == {transform.position.z} is {areEqual}")
```

который выводит в консоль:

```
-1 == -1 is False
```

Я не могу понять почему сравнение между -1 и -1 дает ответ неверно.

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Одинаковые числа с плавающей точкой могут иметь погрешность, для решения таких задач используется слегка другой подход, нежели оператор сравнения:

`bool areEqual = Math.Abs(num1 - num2) < delta;`

---

Поскольку тут конкретно вопрос по `Unity`, то можно воспользоваться специальным методом из библиотеки:

`public static bool Approximately(float a, float b);`

Использование:

`bool areEqual = Mathf.Approximately(tiles[i].transform.position.z, transform.position.z)`