# Как вычисляется значение в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите, почему на кальляторе значение **x*x+x*** равно **0.752001**, а в JavaScript считает как **0.7520009999999999**??? 
Я это значение считаю так: **x+dx=0.5+0.001=0.501**; **xx+x=0.501*0.501+0.501=0.752001**

```
function diff(f,x,dx){
  //Результат функции
  return f(x+dx)
}

//Функция для передачи аргументом
function G(x){
  //Значение функции
  return x*x+x;//0.7520009999999999
}
//Точное значение
function g(x){
  return 2*x+1;
}

for(let z=0.5; z<=2; z+=0.5){
  document.write(g(z)+' vs.'+diff(G,z,0.001)+'<br>')
}
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)