# Как создать массив вещественных число от -1 до +1? Python

Tags: python

Вопрос из разряда нуб, но как задать массив вещественных чисел, в котором будут числа изменяющиеся до сотых? И реально ли такое? 
(Т.е. последовательность типа -1.00, -0.99, -0.98....1.00)
Я попробовал нечто подобное, но не получилось
 mas = list(range(-1.00, 1.01))

Comment: range не работает с вещественными числами. В данном случае можно создать массив от -100 до 100, потом каждый элемент поделить на 100.

Comment: @insolor А это прикольное решение

Comment: `numpy.arange(-1, 1.01, 0.01)`

Comment: @nomnoms12 у такого способа [проблемы с точностью](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453), деление целого числа на 100 даст более корректный результат

Comment: А для чего? А то может у задачи есть более красивое решение, чем создавать список на двести элементов.

Comment: @Эникейщик мне просто нужно изменять переменную в цикле в таком виде

Comment: Ну так сделайте через while.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Несколько извращенский, но точный способ :)

```py
from decimal import Decimal

result = [float(Decimal(i) / 100) for i in range(-100, 101)]
```

Answer (score 2):

Вот функция принимающая начальное и конечное значения, а также число знаков после запятой

```
def real_numbers(fromNumber, toNumber, precision):
    multiplier = 10**precision
    return map(lambda x: x / multiplier, range(fromNumber*multiplier, toNumber*multiplier+1))

list(real_numbers(-1, 1, 2)) # для вашей задачи вызов выглядит так
```

Answer (score 1):

Как вариант:

```
import numpy
x = numpy.arange(-1, 1.01, 0.01)
for i in x:
  print("%.2f" % i)
```