# цикл for и неверный вывод, java

Tags: java, вывод, for, float

При таком коде

```
for (double i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI; i += 0.1) {
            System.out.println(i);

        }
```

на вывод получается нечто подобное

```
0.0

0.1

0.2

0.30000000000000004

0.4

0.5

0.6

0.7

0.7999999999999999

0.8999999999999999

0.9999999999999999

1.0999999999999999
```

и т.д.

а хотелось бы

```
0.0

0.1

0.2

0.3

0.4

0.5
```

и т.д

Не понимаю почему, и как это исправить?

Comment: Это специфика чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Сделайте так

```
for (int i = 0; i < 2 * Math.PI*10; i++) {
  System.out.println(i/10.0);
}
```

Comment: А можно пояснить, как это работает? И чем `i/10.0` отличается от `i*0.1`?

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/219595/  
Вот полезная статья, в конце статьи есть полезные ссылки.  
Рекомендую также почитать про Стандарт IEEE 754, данные "проблемы" с плавающей точкой не только в Java