# Можно ли использовать Typescript без компиляции в JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Я в курсе что TypScript компилируется в JavaScript. Но это потому что браузер не понимает TypeScript, так? Здесь возникает вопрос: Если я использую TypScript только для бекенда?(в Nest Js) потом мне все равно придется компилировать его в JavaScript? Код же работает только на серверах(на NodeJs). Тогда суть TypScriptа в чем? Я понимаю что при разработке Строгая типизация помогает очень хорошо но в JavaScriptе строг.типизация после буилда, все равно не работает же? Javascript могут вычислят ариф.операции не правильно, хотя в TypScriptе перед буилдом работало правильно. Объясните пожалуйста, может я не понимаю что-то? или чего-то пропустил?

Comment: Нельзя использовать TypeScript в node js, потому что node js работает на V8 - интерпретаторе JavaScript.

Comment: @Voprositel а Deno?

Comment: Не могу точно сказать, но думаю, что также компилируется в JavaScript, тк  v8

Comment: Deno точно так же использует V8. Просто комилятор ts -> js встроен прямо в Deno.

Comment: @AlexeyTen Понял. Спасибо

Comment: Можно вместо nodejs использовать deno https://deno.land/

Answer (score 1):

Node.js работает на v8 - движке chrome, следовательно может распознавать ts только после компиляции в js. TypeScript используется для удобства программирования и избежания ошибок, связанных с типизацией, которые в обычном js очень сложно отследить, особенно в крупных проектах. Для использования ts в node.js необходим пакет [typescript](https://www.npmjs.com/package/typescript), который компилирует ts в js.

Comment: Я хотел написать бекенд на TypScriptе/Javascript , но из-за проблема типизации в Javascript, у меня все равно не получается?

Comment: @ДиликПулатов, вы можете писать на TypeScript, а он будет незаметно для вас транспилиться в JavaScript, на работу приложения это влиять не будет.

Comment: Тогда возможно стоило задать вопрос именно с вашей проблемой?

Comment: T0hich71 Проблема в том что в Javascript  есть проблема с вычислении в ариф.операции. Такое было в фронте, Не правильно считала общую сумму заказа. Допустим есть amount = 1251.09. amount * 100 = 125108.99999999999 такой результат дает Javascript, хотя разработка было в TypScriptе

Comment: Я так и не понял, как ваш вопрос связан с проблемой. При чём тут ts?  Вас интересует конкретная проблема или всё же рассуждения на тему "зачем нужен ts"?

Comment: @ДиликПулатов такой ответ даст любой  ЯП использующий операции с плавающей точкой соответствующие стандарту IEEE754 https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/190728 Т.е. практически любой ЯП

Comment: @AlexeyTen Вот как...а то я думал, почему в ТС все работало отлично...а в жс нет. Попробую почитать об этом. Спасибо

Comment: @T0hich71 Вопрос именно в этом: Зачем нужно TS, если она все равно компилируется в JS и при этом в JS проблемы с ариф.операции не решается?

Comment: @ДиликПулатов, [здесь](https://learn.javascript.ru/number#netochnye-vychisleniya) ответ на ваш вопрос

Comment: https://yandex.ru/search?text=зачем+нужен+typescript

Comment: @Voprositel спасибо

Comment: @AlexeyTen гуглит то я умею)