# Почему при добавление вещественных элементов в массив появляются лишние знаки после запятой

Tags: python, python-3.x

Недавно столкнулась со странной проблемой, при добавление вещественного числа в массив, оно дополняется знаками после запятой. Как избежать это проблемы? Пробовала округлять число при добавление или после добавления округлять все числа в массиве - ничего не работает.

```
def f(x):
    return cos(x ** 2) - x * sin(x)

def d(a, b, eps):
    res = []
    x = chord(a, b, eps)
    res.append(x)
    return res
    

def chord(a, b, eps):
    c = 2*eps
    while abs(c-b) > eps:
        tmp = c
        c = b - f(b) * (a-b) / (f(a) - f(b))
        a = b
        b = tmp
    return round(c, 5) 
    
print(chord(0, 8, 1e-5))   
print(d(0, 8, 1e-5))
```

Вывод:
0.89412
[0.89412000000000003]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: добавила)def f(x):
    return cos(x ** 2) - x * sin(x)

Comment: у меня печатается `[0.89412]`. Функции `sin`, `cos` импортированы из `math`?

Comment: нет, были из numpy, из math правда сработали, спасибо!

Comment: тоже самое, все отлично работает если использовать `from math import sin, cos`

Comment: проверил с `numpy==1.19.3`, вывод аналогичен. Никакого непонятного поведения не обнаружено.

Comment: с функциями из numpy тоже все правильно выводит - в общем проблема не воспроизводится