# Как ограничить число по шагу числа?

Tags: javascript

```js
var tick = 0.0001;
var price = 12.94356341;
// 12.9435

var tick = 0.001;
var price = 457.446232;
// 457.446

var tick = 0.02;
var price = 3.9553234;
// 3.94
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
457.446232 / 0.001   → 457446.232
parseInt(457446.232) → 457446
457446 * 0.001       → 457.446
```

```js
console.log( bubu(12.94356341, 0.0001) ); // 12.9435
console.log( bubu(457.446232, 0.001) ); // 457.446
console.log( bubu(3.9553234, 0.02) ); // 3.94

console.log( bubu(457.446232, 0.0027) ); // 457.44480000000004 (упс?)

function bubu(price, tick) {
  return parseInt(price / tick) * tick;
}
```

Для решения последней [» проблемы «](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%D0%92%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%85-%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BB%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%B9-%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B9-%D0%BD%D0%B5-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%8E%D1%82), можно дополнительно отрезать число, оставив столько знаков после запятой, сколько было у tick.

```js
console.log( bubu(457.446232, 0.0027) ); // 457.4448
console.log( bubu(57.4, 17) ); // 51

function bubu(price, tick) {  
  let prec = (String(tick).split('.')[1] || '').length;
  // кол-во цифр после точки.
  // || '' пустая строка предусмотрена на случай, если tick - целое число.
  
  let x = ( parseInt(price / tick) * tick ).toFixed(prec);
  // *toFixed возвращает строку

  return Number(x);
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, вроде все правильно считает

Comment: @Squeli47 * Отредактировано, с учетом случая, если tick - целое число.

Answer (score 1):

```js
var tick = 0.0001;
var price = 12.94356341;
// 12.9435

var tick = 0.001;
var price = 457.446232;
// 457.446

var tick = 0.02;
var price = 3.9553234;
// 3.94

alert(magic(tick, price))

function magic(step, number){
  return(price.toFixed(step.toString().split('.')[1].length))
}
```

непонятно, правда, как 3.95 после "обрезания" превратилось в 3.94

Метод toFixed(n) округляет число до n знаков после запятой и возвращает **строковое представление** результата.

Answer (score 1):

Проще всего так:

```js
price.toFixed(tick.toString().split('.')[1].length);
```

Comment: `(3.9553234).toFixed((0.02).toString().split('.')[1].length);` → строка `"3.96"`, автор ожидает число `3.94` )