# Почему мантисса чисел начинает куда-то ехать?

Tags: c#, числа

Задание было очень простое: параметр а меняет значения от 1.25 до 2 с шагом 0.25, а x от -2 до 2 с шагом 0.1. В файле с результатами ужас какой-то... Все дело в представлении чисел, но как исправить-не знаю.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace тимп_1._2_часть_2
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            StreamWriter p = new StreamWriter("rez.txt");
            float a, x, y2;
            p.WriteLine("        РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ РАСЧЕТА");
            for (a=1; a<=2; a +=0.25f)
            {
                p.WriteLine("  а= " + a);
                for (x = -2; x <= 2; x += 0.1f)
                {
                    y2 = (float)((1 - Math.E* ((-1) * Math.Pow((x / a), 2))) / a);
                    p.WriteLine("     x= " + x + '\t' + "      y= " + y2);
                }
            }
            p.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

мы учимся делать вложенные циклы, в файле просто выводятся значение a, потом все значения х и по формуле считается y во вложенном циклае и так для каждого увеличения а. Мы смотрим на результаты в файле, но у меня они там неровные какие-то, например: вместо х=1,7 после очередной итерации получается число 1,6999999, а не 1,7, и, соответвенно, значения y тоже кривые...

для а=1 x= -1,8 y= 9,807233, а вот при том же а: x= -1,699997 y= 8,855834, а x по циклу должен быть 1,7

Comment: Какое было задание и что должно делать приложение, вы нам конечно же не расскажете.

Comment: Задание было очень простое: параметр а меняет значения от 1.25 до 2 с шагом 0.25, а x от -2 до 2 с шагом 0.1. Результаты итераций выводит в файл "rez.txt"

Comment: Я умею читать. А что делает приложение то? Что оно должно делать? В чем проблема? Что исправить?

Comment: мы учимся делать вложенные циклы, в файле просто выводятся значение a, потом все значения х и по формуле считается y во вложенном циклае и так для каждого увеличения а. Мы смотрим на результаты в файле, но у меня они там неровные какие-то, например: вместо х=1,7 после очередной итерации получается число 1,6999999, а не 1,7, и, соответвенно, значения y тоже кривые...

Comment: для а=1  x= -1,8  y= 9,807233

Comment: а вот при том же а:  x= -1,699997 y= 8,855834, а x по циклу должен быть 1,7

Comment: Вносите уточнения в тело вопроса - кнопка "править".

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453).

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `ToString` отформатирует число ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.single.tostring?view=netcore-3.1)).
- `PadLeft` сделает нужный отступ ([ссылка](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.string.padleft?view=netcore-3.1)).
- Учитесь сразу правильно работать с `IDisposable` объектами, которым является `StreamWriter` - [using](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/using-objects).
- [Интерполяция строк](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) позволяет удобнее форматировать строки, делает код короче.

```cs
using StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("rez.txt");
sw.WriteLine("РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ РАСЧЕТА");
for (float a = 1; a <= 2; a += 0.25f)
{
    sw.WriteLine("а = " + a);
    for (float x = -2; x <= 2; x += 0.1f)
    {
        float y = (1 + MathF.E * MathF.Pow(x / a, 2)) / a;
        sw.WriteLine($"x = {x,4:F1} y = {y,4:F1}");
        //sw.WriteLine("x = " + x.ToString("F1").PadLeft(4) + " y = " + y.ToString("F1").PadLeft(4));
    }
}
```

Вывод в файл

```
РЕЗУЛЬТАТЫ РАСЧЕТА
а = 1
x = -2,0 y = 11,9
x = -1,9 y = 10,8
x = -1,8 y =  9,8
x = -1,7 y =  8,9
x = -1,6 y =  8,0
x = -1,5 y =  7,1
x = -1,4 y =  6,3
x = -1,3 y =  5,6
x = -1,2 y =  4,9
x = -1,1 y =  4,3
...
```

Comment: @МешокКартошки не за что. Еще [вот это](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated) почитайте, пригодится.