# работа с Двумерным массивом C#

Tags: c#

Есть двумерный массив состоящий из вещественных чисел, вычислить:
количество отрицательных элементов в тех строках, где хотя бы один элемент равен нулю

```
        double[,] massiv = new double[,]
         {
             {-13.2, 0, 10.5, -2.4, 5.8 },
             {10.0, 5.6, -4.10, 3.3, -20.13},
             {16.5, 19.3, 0, -11.0, -8.0 }
          };


        int height = massiv.GetLength(0);
        int width = massiv.GetLength(1);
        for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
            {
                Console.Write(massiv[y, x] + "\t");
            }
            Console.WriteLine();
        }


        int z = 0;
        // Действие
        for(int i = 0; i < massiv.Length; i++)
        {
            for(int b = 0; b < massiv.Length; b++)
            {
                if(b == 0 && i < 0)
                {
                    
                    
                }
                
                
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вещественные числа не проверяют на равенство, потому что может быть `0,0000000000000000000000001`,  и это не равно `0`. Вещественные числа проверяют на вхождение в диапазон значений с нужной точностью.

Comment: double[,] massiv = new double[,]
             {
                 {-13.2, 0, 10.5, -2.4, 5.8 },
                 {10.0, 5.6, -4.10, 3.3, -20.13},
                 {16.5, 19.3, 0, -11.0, -8.0 }
              };
могу ли в этом массиве провести эту операцию?

Comment: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/373567)

Comment: Можете, 2 цикла, 1 условие. Но для начала отредактируйте вопрос, добавьте туда ваш массив и код, который вы написали, и он не работает, и опишите, что именно не получается, какие ошибки в каких строках кода возникают.

Comment: ошибок нет вроде, не могу условие понять как записать

Comment: Берете `int` счетчик для строки и `bool` флаг, и начинаете считать в строке отрицательные числа, как только встретили ноль, ставите флаг в `true`, а как прошли всю строку, проверяете флаг, если тру, то добавляете сумму строки к общему счетчику, который и будет впоследствии нужным вам результатом.

Comment: моя проблема в том что я не могу понять как это в коде отобразить, а так это всё я понимаю

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int[] rows_with_query = new int[height];
for (int y = 0; y < height; y++)
{
    bool haszero = false;
    int belowzero = 0;
    for (int x = 0; x < width; x++)
    {
        if (massiv[y, x] == 0) haszero=true;
        if (massiv[y, x] < 0) belowzero++;
        Console.Write($"{massiv[y, x]}\t");
    }
    if (haszero)
    {
        rows_with_query[y] = belowzero;
        Console.Write($"Minuses = {belowzero}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(" ", rows_with_query.Select(s=>s.ToString())));
```

Comment: Точно не помню, но по-соему `Select(s=>s.ToString())` - лишнее.

Comment: @aepot В принципе да, лишнее, просто привычка, но кто знает какая там версия фреймворка и не захочет ли Join сделать внутри int+separator без приведения int к string