# Почему при округлении 1.999...8 получается 0? JS

Tags: javascript, html

Кол-во потопленных кораблей увеличивается на 1 после 3 попаданий по любому из не потопленных кораблей ( всего их три ). 
 
Если потоплен 1 корабль, то все отображается корректно. Если 3, тоже. Но если сбиты только 2, то выводится 1.9999999999999998. 
Пробовал использовать округление ( `Math.ceil` и `Math.round`) - не помогает, получается 0.

 
Очень прошу помочь.

```
isSunk(ship){
    for(var i = 0; i < this.widthShips; i++){
       if(ship.hits[i] !== 'hit'){
          return false;
       }
       return true;
    }
}


for(var i = 0; i < this.numShips; i++){
    var ship = this.ships[i];
    var index = ship.location.indexOf(guess);
      if(index >= 0){
        view.displayHit(guess);
        view.displayMassege('Hit!');
        ship.hits[index] = 'hit';
        if(this.isSunk(ship)){
            view.displayMassege('One battleship is sunk!');
            this.sunkShips = this.sunkShips+1 / 3;
        };
        return true;
     }
}
```

Проверяется кол-во потопленных кораблей после выстрела.

Я округляю значение `sunkShips` .

Comment: Добавь ещё кода. Почему при прибавлении единицы увеличивается на 3?

Comment: какое именно значение ты проверяешь и в какой момент времени???

Comment: и какое именно значение ты округляешь?

Comment: `this.sunkShips+1 / 3` - за такое форматирование руки поотрывать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, стоило все-таки дождаться ответа. До сих пор непонятно, что именно он проверял и округлял

Comment: @Grundy, зачем? Про 1.999... и так понятно. Как считать правильно - тоже понятно. Что он округлял? Ну 1.9 как ни старайся, до 0 не округлится - только до 1 или 2, значит округлял он там, где прибавляет 1/3 и 0 получался всегда: `this.sunkShips = Math.ropund(this.sunkShips+1/3);` Впрочем, как сюда ceil ни пристраивай, всё рано получится 1, 2, 3...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> this.sunkShips = this.sunkShips+1 / 3;

Считай число попаданий целочисленным счётчиком, а при выводе используй `Math.floor(n / 3)` - тогда всё будет работать правильно.

> Пробовал использовать округление ( Math.ceil и Math.round) - не помогает, получается 0.

Если бы пробовал не при добавлении 1/3, а при выводе, то `round` бы помог. Или вообще `.toFixed(0)`. Но надо считать правильно, а не так.

> Но если сбиты только 2, то выводится 1.9999999999999998.

[Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/178988)

Comment: Спасибо, помогло. Извиняюсь за свою тупость и неопытность.