# Округление в пайтоне

Tags: python

Можете, пожалуйста, либо объяснить здесь, либо покидать ссылок. Я запутался в округлении в пайтоне. Можете показать как использовать метод format() именно для округления, не понимаю для чего нужны эти значки (пример: {8.3f}".format(12.2346)). Что лучше использовать для округления: какие модули, функции. И ещё об ошибках, которые могут возникать в питоне (пример: 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.30000000004). И почему эти ошибки возникают.

Comment: В целом, не нужно задавать вопрос содержащий несколько вопросов. По поводу последнего см. [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/417453/1365)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: @insolor спасибо за совет, учту на будующее! Но как быть если есть несколько вопросов, не уж то открывать несколько отдельных тем?

Comment: Здесь нет тем, есть вопросы. В каждом вопросе должен быть один отдельный вопрос.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насчёт "*значков*". В скобках указывается формат числа, то это указание, сколько знаков до запятой и после запятой вы желаете увидеть у числа. Строятся они примерно вот так: `{:x.yf}`, где **x** - общее число знаков в числе, **y** - число знаков после запятой.

Примеры:

```py
"{:2.3f}".format(12.545)  # Вывод: "12.545"
"{:2.5f}".format(12.545)  # Вывод: "12.54500"
"{:2.0f}".format(12.545)  # Вывод: "13"
```

Как видите, если знаков не хватает (2-ой случай), то число дополняется нулями. Если их слишком много (3-ий случай), число округляется. Насколько мне известно, используются стандартные математические правила, то есть (`12.4 -> 12`, `12.5 -> 13`).

Теперь разберёмся с первым числом на примерах:

```py
print("{:2.3f}".format(12.545))  # Вывод: "12.545"
print("{:10.3f}".format(12.545))  # Вывод: "    12.545" - перед числом 4 пробела
print("{:0.3f}".format(12.545))  # Вывод: "12.545"
```

Как видите, если число занимает меньше места, чем указано в первом параметре, то перед ним появятся пробелы, заполняющие место. Это удобно при построении таблиц.

Теперь насчёт "*точности и ошибок вычисления*". Данные ошибки происходят из-за способа представления чисел с плавающей точкой в памяти компьютера. Для этого используется стандарт IEEE754, лучше поискать про него что-то самостоятельно, но если в двух словах: при использовании ограниченного места на одно число приходится жертвовать точностью вычислений.

На практике же это означает, что вычисления с использованием таких чисел всегда происходят с погрешностью. Именно поэтому `>>> 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 != 0.3`. Чтобы сравнивать такие числа можно воспользоваться функцией сравнения разности чисел с заданной точностью. Вот пример:

```py
def compareFloats(f1, f2, epsilon = 0.01):
    calculatedEpsilon = abs(f1 * epsilon)
    difference = abs(f1 - f2)
    return difference < calculatedEpsilon

a = 0.3
b = 0.1+0.1+0.1
print(a == b)               # False
print(compareFloats(a, b))  # True
print(b)                    # 0.30000000000000004
```

(На работоспособность кода не претендую, чисто в показательных целях.)

Comment: Вот хороший ответ на похожий вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/417454/333652

Answer (score 1):

> Можете показать как использовать метод format() именно для округления, не понимаю для чего нужны эти значки (пример: {8.3f}".format(12.2346))

Строковый метод `format()` форматирует строки python для более красивого вывода.

**Как работает `format()`?**

Формат читает тип переданных аргументов и форматирует строку в соответствии с кодами форматирования в строке.

`{8.3f}` - это шаблон строки. Он содержит коды форматирования.

Прочесть вы можете [здесь](https://pythonru.com/osnovy/formatirovanie-v-python-s-pomoshhju-format)

> Что лучше использовать для округления: какие модули, функции.

При выполнении ряда арифметических операций пользователю нужно следовать правилам округления. Преобразовывать нужно в большую или меньшую сторону, до целого значения или до сотых. В Python программисту для этого доступны функции `round()`, `int()` и модуль `math`. Последний дополнительно импортируется.

Про округление подробно [здесь](https://pythonworld.ru/osnovy/okruglenie.html)

> И ещё об ошибках, которые могут возникать в питоне (пример: 0.1 + 0.1 + 0.1 = 0.30000000004). И почему эти ошибки возникают.

Числа с плавающей точкой представлены в компьютерах в виде двоичных дробей. К сожалению, большинство десятичных дробей не могут быть представлены точно как двоичные дроби. Следствием этого является то, что, как правило, вводимые десятичные числа с плавающей запятой аппроксимируются только двоичными числами с плавающей запятой, фактически сохраненными в машине.

Про ошибки в точности `float` [здесь](https://docs-python.ru/tutorial/operatsii-chislami-python/problemy-chisel-plavajuschej-zapjatoj)