# Вывод неверных данных

Tags: java

Я совсем недавно начал учиться программировать на Java, вопрос следующий: решил немного усложнить одно из упражнений по Шилдту и вместо уже заданного значения переменной dist предлагаю юзеру ввести это значение.

```
class Vehicle{
int passengers;
int fuelcap;
int mpg;

Vehicle (int p, int f, int m) {
passengers=p;
fuelcap=f;
mpg=m;
}

int range() {
return mpg*fuelcap;

}

double fuelneeded(int miles) {

return (double) miles/mpg;
}
}

class VehConsDemo1 {

public static void main(String args[])

throws java.io.IOException{

Vehicle minivan=new Vehicle(7,16,21);

Vehicle sportscar=new Vehicle(12,14,12);

double gallons;

int dist;

System.out.println("Введите количество миль для рассчета");
dist=(int)System.in.read();

gallons=minivan.fuelneeded(dist);

System.out.println("Для преодоления " + dist + " миль фургону нужно " + gallons + " галлонов топлива");

gallons=sportscar.fuelneeded(dist);

System.out.println("Для преодоления " + dist + " миль спорткару нужно " + gallons + " галлонов топлива");
}
}
```

Собственно, вся проблема в том, что я ввожу условные 100 (миль), на выходе получаются совсем другие результаты. Что делаю не так? Заранее благодарю.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: даже если в инт все перевести, ошибка остается. Я ввожу "100", мне считает для 49.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`System.in.read()` - читает один байт
Если вы хотите прочитать пользовательский ввод, используйте хотя бы сканер

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
dist = sc.nextInt();
```