# Как округлить полученное число с value?

Tags: javascript

Подскажите пожалуйста, как округлить сумму вычислений, оставив только одно число после точки

Пример: 100 / 0.0030301 = 33002.211148146926
Должно быть так: 100 / 0.0030301 = 33002.2

Пример кода:

```js
let oneItem = $(".range-price-item-1 p");

let sumItem = $(".range-price-item-3 p");

$('#range-yellow').range({
  min: 100,
  max: 1000,
  start: 100,
  step: 100,
  onChange: function(value) {
    
     $('#display-3').html(value);
    sumItem.text(+value / +oneItem.text());
  }
});
```

```html
<div class="range-input">
  <div class="ui yellow range" id="range-yellow">
    <p>
      Value: <span id="display-3"></span>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="range-price">
  <div class="range-price-item">
    <div class="range-price-item-1">
      <h1>Первое значение</h1>
      <p>0.0030301</p>
    </div>
    <div class="range-price-item-2">
      <h1>Второе значение</h1>
      Value: <span id="display-3"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="range-price-item-3">
      <h1>Итоговая сумма</h1>
      <p>0</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/round

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Вычисления на числах с плавающей точкой не работают](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/417453/%d0%92%d1%8b%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%87%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%85-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%bb%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d1%82%d0%be%d1%87%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%bd%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8e%d1%82)

Comment: `let rounded = Number(Math.round((100 / 0.0030301)+'e1')+'e-1')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можете воспользоваться `toFixed(n)`, где `n` - количество цифр после запятой.   Внимание `toFixed(n)` возвращает строку с Вашим числом.

```js
let num = 100 / 0.0030301
console.log(num.toFixed(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Можно так:

```
function round(value){
return Math.floor(value*10)/10
}
```

Тогда получится:

```
let oneItem = $(".range-price-item-1 p");

let sumItem = $(".range-price-item-3 p");

function round(value){
    return Math.floor(value*10)/10
    }

$('#range-yellow').range({
  min: 100,
  max: 1000,
  start: 100,
  step: 100,
  onChange: function(value) {
    
     $('#display-3').html(value);
    sumItem.text(round(+value / +oneItem.text()));
  }
});
```

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]